# 'Fill' Unicode characters in labels

Tags: java, swing, unicode, background, character

How to 'fill' Unicode characters in labels in Swing?

[image]

I'm trying to make a user interface for the chess program I've recently programmed
(with chess pieces something like seen above).  In it I'm using unicode characters to represent my chess pieces (`\u2654` through `\u265F`).

The problem is as follows:

When I set the background of my chess piece `JLabel` to something like white, the entire label is filled (in my case it's a 50*50px square of white with the character on top).  This leads to my pieces looking like tiles instead of just their pictures.

When I set the label to opaque, I just get a cookie cutter version of my chess piece, not one with its insides filled. E.G.

[image: Actual result]

Is there a way to fill only the character?

If not I guess I'll make a sprite sheet but I like this because I can use the chess pieces' `toString()` methods for the labels.

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

class ChessBoard {

    static Font font = new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.PLAIN, 50);
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void addUnicodeCharToContainer(
        String s, Container c, boolean randomColor) {

        JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
        l.setFont(font);
        if (randomColor) {
            int r = rnd.nextInt(255);
            int g = rnd.nextInt(255);
            int b = rnd.nextInt(255);

            l.setForeground(new Color(r,g,b));
            l.setBackground(new Color(255-r,255-g,255-b));
            l.setOpaque(true);
        }
        c.add(l);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,6,4,4));

                String[] pieces = {
                    "\u2654","\u2655","\u2656","\u2657","\u2658","\u2659",
                    "\u265A","\u265B","\u265C","\u265D","\u265E","\u265F"
                };

                for (String piece : pieces) {
                    addUnicodeCharToContainer(piece,gui,false);
                }
                for (String piece : pieces) {
                    addUnicodeCharToContainer(piece,gui,true);
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: I am confused. Do your images for your chest pieces support and implement transparency? If so, why don't you just fill the character using an image editor like GIMP?

Comment: @mKorbel  I was so fascinated by the question that I was compelled to try it.  See new image and SSCCE in the question that I hope should make it more clear.

Comment: See also the [UGlys - Unicode Glyphs](https://github.com/andrewthommo/UGlys) code repository - inspired by this question (screenshot below). :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: Chess Pieces]

The two rows are generated through the sorcery of Java-2D.  The trick is to:

- Ignore the 'black' chess pieces on the basis that our color is actually coming from 'the spaces contained by the shape'.  Those are larger in the white chess pieces.
- Create a `GlyphVector` that represents the shape of the character.  This is important for further operations in Java-2D.
- Create a `Rectangle` the size of the image.
- `subtract()` the shape of the character from the shape of the image.
- *Break that altered shape into regions.*
- Fill the regions with the background color, but ***skip the single region*** that starts at 0.0,0.0 (representing the outermost region which we need transparent).
- Finally, fill the shape of the character itself using the outline color.

#### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class ChessBoard {

    static Font font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 50);
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static ArrayList<Shape> separateShapeIntoRegions(Shape shape) {
        ArrayList<Shape> regions = new ArrayList<Shape>();

        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null);
        int ii = 0;
        GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
        while (!pi.isDone()) {
            double[] coords = new double[6];
            int pathSegmentType = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            int windingRule = pi.getWindingRule();
            gp.setWindingRule(windingRule);
            if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO) {
                gp = new GeneralPath();
                gp.setWindingRule(windingRule);
                gp.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
                System.out.println(ii++ + " \t" + coords[0] + "," + coords[1]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO) {
                gp.lineTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO) {
                gp.quadTo(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO) {
                gp.curveTo(
                        coords[0], coords[1],
                        coords[2], coords[3],
                        coords[4], coords[5]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
                gp.closePath();
                regions.add(new Area(gp));
            } else {
                System.err.println("Unexpected value! " + pathSegmentType);
            }

            pi.next();
        }

        return regions;
    }

    public static void addColoredUnicodeCharToContainer(
            String s, Container c,
            Color bgColor, Color outlineColor, boolean blackSquare) {

        int sz = font.getSize();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                sz, sz, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);

        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, s);
        Rectangle2D box1 = gv.getVisualBounds();

        Shape shape1 = gv.getOutline();
        Rectangle r = shape1.getBounds();
        System.out.println("shape rect: " + r);
        int spaceX = sz - r.width;
        int spaceY = sz - r.height;
        AffineTransform trans = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                -r.x + (spaceX / 2), -r.y + (spaceY / 2));
        System.out.println("Box2D " + trans);

        Shape shapeCentered = trans.createTransformedShape(shape1);

        Shape imageShape = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, sz, sz);
        Area imageShapeArea = new Area(imageShape);
        Area shapeArea = new Area(shapeCentered);
        imageShapeArea.subtract(shapeArea);
        ArrayList<Shape> regions = separateShapeIntoRegions(imageShapeArea);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        for (Shape region : regions) {
            Rectangle r1 = region.getBounds();
            if (r1.getX() < 0.001 && r1.getY() < 0.001) {
            } else {
                g.setColor(bgColor);
                g.fill(region);
            }
        }
        g.setColor(outlineColor);
        g.fill(shapeArea);
        g.dispose();

        JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi), JLabel.CENTER);
        Color bg = (blackSquare ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        l.setBackground(bg);
        l.setOpaque(true);
        c.add(l);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 6, 4, 4));

                String[] pieces = {
                    "\u2654", "\u2655", "\u2656", "\u2657", "\u2658", "\u2659"
                };

                boolean blackSquare = false;
                for (String piece : pieces) {
                    addColoredUnicodeCharToContainer(
                            piece, gui,
                            new Color(203,203,197),
                            Color.DARK_GRAY,
                            blackSquare);
                            blackSquare = !blackSquare;
                }
                            blackSquare = !blackSquare;
                for (String piece : pieces) {
                    addColoredUnicodeCharToContainer(
                            piece, gui,
                            new Color(192,142,60),
                            Color.DARK_GRAY,
                            blackSquare);
                            blackSquare = !blackSquare;
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

### Chess Board

This is what it might look like as a [Chess Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/222NX.png) (22.81 Kb).

> [image: Chess Board Unadorned]

### Sprite sets

Sprite sets of chess pieces (64x64 pixel) rendered from Unicode characters - as a PNG with transparent BG. Each has 6 columns for the pieces x 2 rows for the opponents (total size 384x128 pixels).

[Chess pieces with solid fill (bronze/pewter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeZ5y.png) (11.64Kb).

> [image: Chess Piece Tile Set]

[Chess pieces with gradient fill (gold/silver)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXWq6.png) (13.61Kb).

> [image: Chess Piece Tile Set with Gradient Fill Color]

[Chess pieces with gradient fill (darker cyan/magenta)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZTI1.png) (13.44Kb).

> [image: Chess Piece Tile Set with Gradient Fill Color]

#### Code for Chess Board & Sprite Set

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

class ChessBoard {

    /**
     * Unicodes for chess pieces.
     */
    static final String[] pieces = {
        "\u2654", "\u2655", "\u2656", "\u2657", "\u2658", "\u2659"
    };
    static final int KING = 0, QUEEN = 1, CASTLE = 2,
            BISHOP = 3, KNIGHT = 4, PAWN = 5;
    public static final int[] order = new int[]{
        CASTLE, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, CASTLE
    };

    /*
     * Colors..
     */
    public static final Color outlineColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;
    public static final Color[] pieceColors = {
        new Color(203, 203, 197), new Color(192, 142, 60)
    };
    static final int WHITE = 0, BLACK = 1;

    /*
     * Font. The images use the font sizeXsize.
     */
    static Font font = new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.PLAIN, 64);

    public static ArrayList<Shape> separateShapeIntoRegions(Shape shape) {
        ArrayList<Shape> regions = new ArrayList<Shape>();

        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null);
        int ii = 0;
        GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
        while (!pi.isDone()) {
            double[] coords = new double[6];
            int pathSegmentType = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            int windingRule = pi.getWindingRule();
            gp.setWindingRule(windingRule);
            if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO) {
                gp = new GeneralPath();
                gp.setWindingRule(windingRule);
                gp.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO) {
                gp.lineTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO) {
                gp.quadTo(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO) {
                gp.curveTo(
                        coords[0], coords[1],
                        coords[2], coords[3],
                        coords[4], coords[5]);
            } else if (pathSegmentType == PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
                gp.closePath();
                regions.add(new Area(gp));
            } else {
                System.err.println("Unexpected value! " + pathSegmentType);
            }

            pi.next();
        }

        return regions;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getImageForChessPiece(
            int piece, int side, boolean gradient) {
        int sz = font.getSize();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                sz, sz, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);

        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
        GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, pieces[piece]);
        Rectangle2D box1 = gv.getVisualBounds();

        Shape shape1 = gv.getOutline();
        Rectangle r = shape1.getBounds();
        int spaceX = sz - r.width;
        int spaceY = sz - r.height;
        AffineTransform trans = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                -r.x + (spaceX / 2), -r.y + (spaceY / 2));

        Shape shapeCentered = trans.createTransformedShape(shape1);

        Shape imageShape = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, sz, sz);
        Area imageShapeArea = new Area(imageShape);
        Area shapeArea = new Area(shapeCentered);
        imageShapeArea.subtract(shapeArea);
        ArrayList<Shape> regions = separateShapeIntoRegions(imageShapeArea);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g.setColor(pieceColors[side]);
        Color baseColor = pieceColors[side];
        if (gradient) {
            Color c1 = baseColor.brighter();
            Color c2 = baseColor;
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                    sz/2-(r.width/4), sz/2-(r.height/4), c1, 
                    sz/2+(r.width/4), sz/2+(r.height/4), c2, 
                    false);
            g.setPaint(gp);
        } else {
            g.setColor(baseColor);
        }

        for (Shape region : regions) {
            Rectangle r1 = region.getBounds();
            if (r1.getX() < 0.001 && r1.getY() < 0.001) {
            } else {
                g.fill(region);
            }
        }
        g.setColor(outlineColor);
        g.fill(shapeArea);
        g.dispose();

        return bi;
    }

    public static void addColoredUnicodeCharToContainer(
            Container c,
            int piece,
            int side,
            Color bg,
            boolean gradient) {

        JLabel l = new JLabel(
                new ImageIcon(getImageForChessPiece(piece, side, gradient)),
                JLabel.CENTER);
        l.setBackground(bg);
        l.setOpaque(true);
        c.add(l);
    }

    public static void addPiecesToContainer(
            Container c,
            int intialSquareColor,
            int side,
            int[] pieces,
            boolean gradient) {

        for (int piece : pieces) {
            addColoredUnicodeCharToContainer(
                    c, piece, side,
                    intialSquareColor++%2 == BLACK ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE,
                    gradient);
        }
    }

    public static void addPiecesToContainer(
            Container c,
            Color bg,
            int side,
            int[] pieces,
            boolean gradient) {

        for (int piece : pieces) {
            addColoredUnicodeCharToContainer(
                    c, piece, side, bg, gradient);
        }
    }

    public static void addBlankLabelRow(Container c, int initialSquareColor) {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel();
            Color bg = (initialSquareColor++ % 2 == BLACK
                    ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            l.setBackground(bg);
            l.setOpaque(true);
            c.add(l);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] pawnRow = new int[]{
            PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN, PAWN
        };
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int gradient = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        null, "Use gradient fille color?");
                boolean gradientFill = gradient == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION;
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 8, 0, 0));
                gui.setBorder(new BevelBorder(
                        BevelBorder.LOWERED,
                        Color.GRAY.brighter(), Color.GRAY,
                        Color.GRAY.darker(), Color.GRAY));
                // set up a chess board
                addPiecesToContainer(gui, WHITE, BLACK, order, gradientFill);
                addPiecesToContainer(gui, BLACK, BLACK, pawnRow, gradientFill);

                addBlankLabelRow(gui, WHITE);
                addBlankLabelRow(gui, BLACK);
                addBlankLabelRow(gui, WHITE);
                addBlankLabelRow(gui, BLACK);

                addPiecesToContainer(gui, WHITE, WHITE, pawnRow, gradientFill);
                addPiecesToContainer(gui, BLACK, WHITE, order, gradientFill);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null,
                        gui,
                        "Chessboard",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                JPanel tileSet = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 6, 0, 0));
                tileSet.setOpaque(false);
                int[] tileSetOrder = new int[]{
                    KING, QUEEN, CASTLE, KNIGHT, BISHOP, PAWN
                };
                addPiecesToContainer(
                        tileSet,
                        new Color(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        BLACK,
                        tileSetOrder, 
                        gradientFill);
                addPiecesToContainer(
                        tileSet,
                        new Color(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        WHITE,
                        tileSetOrder, 
                        gradientFill);
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        null,
                        tileSet,
                        "Save this tileset?",
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                            tileSet.getWidth(),
                            tileSet.getHeight(),
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
                    tileSet.paint(g);
                    g.dispose();

                    String gradientString = gradientFill ? "gradient" : "solid";
                    File f = new File(
                            "chess-pieces-tileset-" + gradientString + ".png");
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", f);
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(
                                ChessBoard.class.getName()).log(
                                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

### See also

- Developed out of the `GlyphVector` code as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556).

[image]

- Resulted in [UGlys - Unicode Glyphs](https://github.com/andrewthommo/UGlys) at GitHub.

[image]

Comment: The required glyphs, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513), start at [`\u2654`](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf)).

Comment: @trashgod  I'd forgotten that nice little example. :)  On a side note, it turned out to be a **lot** harder to turn my idea into working code than I'd thought it would be!  To be honest, I am stumped as to how to achieve this exact requirement with those symbols.  If you have any brilliant ideas, now would be a great time for them.  ;)

Comment: Hmn, maybe `setOpaque(false)` in a label that implements `Icon`.

Comment: @trashgod  OK.  But the twist is that ..the way I understand the problem, those 'two color' images above, should be 3 colors, with the third color being one that 'fills' the holes inside the chess piece that are currently appearing as the BG color.  The only equivalent to those holes in the `Cat` image is the 'tear like' thing coming from the eye of the pussy-cat, in the `a`.  No amount of adding or subtracting `Shape` instances that I know, would give the area that is 'only the tear'.  I'm almost at the point where I recommend to take option 'b' - *"make a sprite sheet"*.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  I started thinking of XOR'ing the black and white pieces' respective pixels to find the background but it all got too complicated too quickly.  A spritesheet is easier, although not nearly as flexible.  Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I see what you mean; I think part of the problem is inherent in the glyph design, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18691662/230513).

Comment: @mKorbel  Thanks.  :)  To be honest, the major part of figuring that out was successfully creating a 'clone' (or in this case, cloneS) of the original area that I could change (or ignore) according to my own custom logic.  That is something I've tried before on various shape related problems (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7218309/418556)), but never managed to achieve ..until just now!

Comment: @AndrewThompson excelent, I suppose that the/our world is not ready to perfection this nature/type of

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.  BTW - Happy 3 figure rep.  :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem I see is that the glyphs were designed to easily distinguish traditional black and white chess pieces. Note also the variation in font design. You may be able to create hue-themed pieces that preserve the black and white distinction using the [HSB color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space). Green and cyan are pictured below.

[image: HSB image]

Addendum: For reference, here's a Mac OS X screenshot of @Andrew's [glyph shape approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686753/230513). Note the benefit of @Andrew's use of `RenderingHints` as the image is scaled.

[image: shape image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18691662/230513 */

class ChessBoard {

    static Font font = new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.PLAIN, 64);
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void addUnicodeCharToContainer(String s, Container c) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
        l.setFont(font);
        l.setOpaque(true);
        c.add(l);
    }

    public static void addWhite(String s, Container c, Float h) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
        l.setFont(font);
        l.setOpaque(true);
        l.setForeground(Color.getHSBColor(h, 1, 1));
        l.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(h, 3 / 8f, 5 / 8f));
        c.add(l);
    }

    public static void addBlack(String s, Container c, Float h) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
        l.setFont(font);
        l.setOpaque(true);
        l.setForeground(Color.getHSBColor(h, 5 / 8f, 3 / 8f));
        l.setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(h, 7 / 8f, 7 / 8f));
        c.add(l);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 6, 4, 4));
                String[] white = {
                    "\u2654", "\u2655", "\u2656", "\u2657", "\u2658", "\u2659"
                };
                String[] black = {
                    "\u265A", "\u265B", "\u265C", "\u265D", "\u265E", "\u265F"
                };
                for (String piece : white) {
                    addUnicodeCharToContainer(piece, gui);
                }
                for (String piece : white) {
                    addWhite(piece, gui, 2 / 6f);
                }
                for (String piece : black) {
                    addUnicodeCharToContainer(piece, gui);
                }
                for (String piece : black) {
                    addBlack(piece, gui, 3 / 6f);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Being able to change the pieces' hue is interesting, but the problem with background/foreground is that I can't distinguish the 'background' that is inside of my chess piece from the real background outside of it.  As @Andrew Thompson said earlier, there are pretty much three colors involved (inside, outside, and the black outline of the glyph).  I always want the inside to be white and the outline to be black, but I want the outside to be transparent.

Comment: @PearSquirrel: I have to disagree mildly; there is only _inside_ and _outside_ the glyph shape; the shape may _enclose_ areas that are _outside_ that shape. You can create your own `Shape` and provide a way to specify different colors for stroke, fill and background.

Comment: Thanks much for the addendum ref. image.  :) As expected of the OS X Sans-Serif font (Helvetica?), it is quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I found making a spritesheet to be the easier and simpler way to go about the problem.  Each piece now corresponds to a graphic within the spritesheet instead of a character/glyph.  Because of this, the pieces can't be resized as nicely but that's not the biggest deal.

@Andrew Thompson's idea with the GlyphVector seemed promising, but the matter of separating inner white space from outer white space remains difficult.

One (inefficient) idea I still have is to make a ton of chess piece glyphs starting from a very small font size and with a foregound color of white:

```
for (int i = 1; i < BOARD_WIDTH/8) { 
JLabel chessPiece =new JLabel("\u2654");
chessPiece.setForeground(Color.white);
chessPiece.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.PLAIN, i));
add(chessPiece);
}
```

then add one last chess piece with a black foreground:

```
JLabel chessPiece =new JLabel("\u2654");
chessPiece.setForeground(Color.black);
chessPiece.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.PLAIN, BOARD_WIDTH/8)));
add(chessPiece);
```

Note that I haven't tested this out.

Comment: have look at GlassPane or JLayer

Comment: Using `deriveFont()` may be helpful.