# Character display/search for Unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, awt

While answering another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18686199/418556) about these parts, I became curious about the glyphs that might be obtained from the Unicode characters as displayed by the available fonts on the system.

Of course there are 65,536 Unicode chars, and over 250 fonts on a typical machine!  Leaves one wondering where to start.  What would be wonderful is an app. that allows us to browse tables of the code points of Unicode as displayed in ..any font selected in a list.  It would be nice to also have:

- A spinner that allows us to jump to any code point of interest.
- The names of the less obscure Unicodes in a list, with a text search editable combo.
- Details on a particular selected Unicode point, including:

  - A big display of the character or glyph, so we can eyeball it.
  - a list of fonts that can display it.
  - The attributes of the code point.

Does such an app. exist?

It might look, well ..something like this!

[image: Unicode Glyph Browser]

Comment: Note this code might be improved in any number of ways, but I ran out of time, budget and ..mostly, character limit on the answer.  Only a few more lines and the site would have refused the reply!

Comment: The question asks for existing software and isn’t really about programming. It has some incorrect premises (e.g., Unicode has now 110,117 characters). The environment has not been specified, and it is unclear whether e.g. BabelMap would satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  *"has some incorrect premises (e.g., Unicode has now 110,117 characters)."*  Thanks for the tip. I'll look into it. *"The environment has not been specified,"*  DYM 'desktop computers'?  Basically anything that is not a headless environment and will run Java *"..and it is unclear whether e.g. BabelMap would satisfy the requirements."*  Given it is for Windows only, no.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  Thanks again.  Changing the '65536' to 110117 showed characters defined up to code point 92,728 - which is apparently 'Bamum Letter Phase-F VUEQ'.  Huh..  As to..  *"isn’t really about programming"*.  Good point.  I'll delete it in a few days..  Now it is up on GitHub at https://github.com/andrewthommo/UGlys it seems redundant here anyway.

Comment: 110,117 is the current number of characters, not the size of the coding space. Unicode numbers run from 0 to 0x10FFFF. You would need information about assigned code points to avoid trying to show unassigned code points as characters. If this is really about *writing* rather than *finding* a program for a specific purpose, then I think you should rephrase the question and explain the *programming* problem(s). And you might be interested in my [Full Unicode input utility](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8) written in JavaScript.

Comment: *"If this is really about writing rather than finding a program for a specific purpose, then I think you should rephrase the question and explain the programming problem(s)."*  Interesting thought.  Maybe I can rework it accommodate that change.  But for the moment on other matters..

Comment: *"you might be interested in my Full Unicode input utility written in JavaScript."*  Yes I am.  Very nice.  I particularly like the `Block:` drop-down in the upper left & have decided I want to incorporate something similar in UGlys.  Do you know of a single source for those planes and blocks (that does not involve trawling through every ISO document dedicated to Unicode)?  I'm looking at the source of the page right now, and wondering if you would allow me to use the JS code (I can adapt it) for my needs.  I would add whatever attribs. required ('Courtesy of .. with no endorsement implied'?).

Comment: Blocks: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Blocks.txt

Comment: Planes: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch02.pdf clause 2.8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure.  Give this a run.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class UnicodeExplorer {

    public static final int codePointColumnWidth = 16;
    public static final int numberUnicodes = 256 * 256;
    private final ArrayList<Font> fontList = new ArrayList<Font>();
    private final SpinnerNumberModel startPage = new SpinnerNumberModel(
            0, 0, numberUnicodes, 1);
    private Font[] fontArray;
    private JList<Font> fonts = new JList<Font>(fontArray);
    private final FontTableCellRenderer fontTableCellRenderer =
            new FontTableCellRenderer();
    private final JTable codePointTable = new JTable(new CodePointTableModel(
            numberUnicodes / codePointColumnWidth, codePointColumnWidth));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 3, 2, 3));

                UnicodeExplorer ue = new UnicodeExplorer();
                ue.initGui(gui);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("UGlys - Unicode Glyphs");
                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                ue.setCharacterSpinner(new Integer(65));
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }

    public void handleCodePointTableSelection(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int row = codePointTable.getSelectedRow();
            int col = codePointTable.getSelectedColumn();
            int codePoint = (row * codePointColumnWidth) + col;
            setCodePointDetailView(codePoint);
        }
    }
    JPanel characterPanel = null;
    JList<Font> supportedFonts = new JList<Font>();
    JLabel bigCharacter = new JLabel();
    JLabel characterDetails = new JLabel();

    public void setFontsForThisCodePoint(int codePoint) {
        DefaultListModel<Font> dlm = new DefaultListModel<Font>();
        for (Font font : fontArray) {
            if (font.canDisplay(codePoint)) {
                dlm.addElement(font);
            }
        }
        supportedFonts.setModel(dlm);
        supportedFonts.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    }

    public void setCodePointDetailView(int codePoint) {
        String s = UnicodeUtil.getCodePointString(codePoint);
        bigCharacter.setText(s);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html><body><table>");
        sb.append(getTableRow("Character", s));
        sb.append(getTableRow("Name", "" + Character.getName(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow("Code Point", "" + codePoint));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Defined", "" + Character.isDefined(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is BMP", "" + Character.isBmpCodePoint(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is ISO Control", "" + Character.isISOControl(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Mirrored", "" + Character.isMirrored(codePoint)));

        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Digit", "" + Character.isDigit(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Letter", "" + Character.isLetter(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Alphabetic", "" + Character.isAlphabetic(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Ideographic", "" + Character.isIdeographic(codePoint)));

        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Space Character", "" + Character.isSpaceChar(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is White Space", "" + Character.isWhitespace(codePoint)));

        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Lower Case", "" + Character.isLowerCase(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Title Case", "" + Character.isTitleCase(codePoint)));
        sb.append(getTableRow(
                "Is Upper Case", "" + Character.isUpperCase(codePoint)));


        sb.append("</table></body></html>");
        characterDetails.setText(sb.toString());

        setFontsForThisCodePoint(codePoint);
    }

    public String getTableRow(String key, String value) {
        return "<tr><th>" + key + "</th><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
    }

    public Component getCharacterPanel() {
        if (characterPanel == null) {
            characterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

            JPanel characterAndFonts = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
            characterAndFonts.add(bigCharacter, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            characterAndFonts.add(
                    new JScrollPane(supportedFonts), BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(
                    JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                    characterAndFonts,
                    new JScrollPane(characterDetails));

            characterPanel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            supportedFonts.setCellRenderer(new FontCellRenderer());
            ListSelectionListener lsl = new ListSelectionListener() {

                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    selectFont(supportedFonts.getSelectedValue());
                }
            };
            supportedFonts.addListSelectionListener(lsl);
        }

        return characterPanel;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void initGui(Container c) {
        if (fontList.size() != 0) {
            return;
        }

        GraphicsEnvironment ge =
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fontNameArray = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

        codePointTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, fontTableCellRenderer);
        codePointTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        codePointTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        ListSelectionModel lsm = codePointTable.getSelectionModel();
        lsm.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        ListSelectionListener codePointListSelectionListener =
                new ListSelectionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        handleCodePointTableSelection(e);
                    }
                };
        codePointTable.getSelectionModel().
                addListSelectionListener(codePointListSelectionListener);

        TableColumnModelListener tcml = new TableColumnModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                handleCodePointTableSelection(e);
            }
        };
        codePointTable.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(tcml);

        Logger.getLogger(
                UnicodeExplorer.class.getCanonicalName()).log(
                Level.INFO, "fontNameArray: " + fontNameArray.length);
        fontArray = new Font[fontNameArray.length];
        String[] logicalFonts = {
            Font.DIALOG, Font.DIALOG_INPUT,
            Font.MONOSPACED,
            Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.SERIF
        };
        for (int ii = 0; ii < logicalFonts.length; ii++) {
            Font f = new Font(logicalFonts[ii], Font.PLAIN, 1);
            fontArray[ii] = f;
            fontList.add(f);
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < fontNameArray.length; ii++) {
            Font f = new Font(fontNameArray[ii], Font.PLAIN, 1);
            if (!fontList.contains(f)) {
                fontArray[logicalFonts.length + count++] = f;
                fontList.add(f);
            }
        }

        Logger.getLogger(
                UnicodeExplorer.class.getCanonicalName()).log(
                Level.INFO, "fontArray: " + fontArray.length);

        fonts = new JList<Font>(fontArray);
        fonts.setCellRenderer(new FontCellRenderer());
        fonts.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        Dimension d = fonts.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension d1 = new Dimension(
                (int) (d.getWidth() / 3), (int) d.getHeight());
        fonts.setPreferredSize(d1);
        ListSelectionListener lsl = new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int index = fonts.getSelectedIndex();
                if (index < 0) {
                    index = 0;
                }
                Font f = fontArray[index].deriveFont(32f);
                fontTableCellRenderer.setDisplayFont(f);
                codePointTable.setRowHeight(f.getSize());
                bigCharacter.setFont(f.deriveFont(128f));
            }
        };
        fonts.addListSelectionListener(lsl);
        JScrollPane fontScroll = new JScrollPane(fonts);

        JPanel tools = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JSpinner page = new JSpinner(startPage);
        tools.add(page);
        ChangeListener cl = new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                int index = startPage.getNumber().intValue();
                selectCodePoint(index);
            }
        };
        page.addChangeListener(cl);

        JPanel codePointTableComponent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        codePointTableComponent.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JScrollPane codePointTableScroll = new JScrollPane(codePointTable);

        ArrayList<Integer> namedCodePoints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final FilteredCodePointListModel namedCodePointListModel =
                new FilteredCodePointListModel();
        ListCellRenderer namedCodePointListeCellRenderer =
                new CodePointListCellRenderer();

        String s;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < numberUnicodes; ii++) {
            s = Character.getName(ii);
            if (s != null) {
                s = s.trim().toLowerCase();
                if (!s.startsWith("null")
                        && !s.contains("private")
                        && !s.contains("cjk")
                        && !s.contains("surrogate")) {
                    namedCodePoints.add(ii);
                    namedCodePointListModel.addElement(new Integer(ii));
                }
            }
        }
        final JList<Integer> namedCodePointList =
                new JList<Integer>(namedCodePointListModel);
        ListSelectionListener namedCodePointListSelectionListener =
                new ListSelectionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                            Integer i = namedCodePointList.getSelectedValue();
                            startPage.setValue(i);
                        }
                    }
                };
        namedCodePointList.addListSelectionListener(
                namedCodePointListSelectionListener);
        namedCodePointList.setCellRenderer(namedCodePointListeCellRenderer);
        namedCodePointList.setVisibleRowCount(8);

        namedCodePointListModel.setFilter("");

        HashMap<String, Integer> namePartMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < namedCodePoints.size(); ii++) {
            String name = Character.getName(namedCodePoints.get(ii));
            String[] parts = name.split(" ");
            for (String part : parts) {
                if (namePartMap.containsKey(part)) {
                    Integer num = namePartMap.get(part);
                    namePartMap.put(part, num.intValue() + 1);
                } else {
                    namePartMap.put(part, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        int namePartMapSize = namePartMap.size();

        class PartNumber implements Comparable {

            public String part;
            public int number;

            PartNumber(String part, int number) {
                this.part = part;
                this.number = number;
            }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(Object o) {
                PartNumber partNumber2 = (PartNumber) o;
                if (number == partNumber2.number) {
                    return part.compareTo(partNumber2.part);
                } else {
                    return number - partNumber2.number;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Part: " + part + " \tnumber: " + number;
            }
        }
        ArrayList<PartNumber> partNumbers = new ArrayList<PartNumber>();
        Set keySet = namePartMap.keySet();
        Iterator it = keySet.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            int number = (Integer) namePartMap.get(key);
            if (key.length() > 4 && number > 7) {
                partNumbers.add(new PartNumber(key, number));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(partNumbers);

        partNumbers.add(new PartNumber("", 0));
        String[] names = new String[partNumbers.size()];
        for (int jj = 0; jj < names.length; jj++) {
            names[jj] = partNumbers.get(jj).part;
        }
        Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(names));

        JComboBox<String> codePointNameFilterCombo =
                new JComboBox<String>(names);
        codePointNameFilterCombo.setEditable(true);

        ComboBoxEditor cbe = new BasicComboBoxEditor();
        final JTextField tf = (JTextField) cbe.getEditorComponent();
        Document doc = tf.getDocument();
        DocumentListener dl = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                namedCodePointListModel.setFilter(tf.getText());
                refreshList();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                namedCodePointListModel.setFilter(tf.getText());
                refreshList();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                namedCodePointListModel.setFilter(tf.getText());
                refreshList();
            }

            private void refreshList() {
                namedCodePointList.repaint();
                namedCodePointList.scrollRectToVisible(
                        namedCodePointList.getCellBounds(0, 0));
            }
        };
        doc.addDocumentListener(dl);
        codePointNameFilterCombo.setEditor(cbe);

        codePointNameFilterCombo.setEditor(cbe);

        namedCodePointListModel.setFilter("");

        //codePointNameFilterCombo
        JPanel namedCodePointPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        namedCodePointPanel.add(
                codePointNameFilterCombo, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        Dimension sizeOfNamedCodePointList = namedCodePointList.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension thinnerSizeOfNamedCodePointList = new Dimension(
                sizeOfNamedCodePointList.width / 4, sizeOfNamedCodePointList.height);
        namedCodePointList.setPreferredSize(thinnerSizeOfNamedCodePointList);
        namedCodePointPanel.add(
                new JScrollPane(namedCodePointList), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JSplitPane codePointTableNameSplit = new JSplitPane(
                JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                codePointTableScroll,
                namedCodePointPanel);
        codePointTableNameSplit.setResizeWeight(1d);
        codePointTableComponent.add(codePointTableNameSplit, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(
                JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                fontScroll, codePointTableComponent);
        selectFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 1));

        JSplitPane splitTopBottom = new JSplitPane(
                JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, split, getCharacterPanel());
        c.add(splitTopBottom, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void setCharacterSpinner(Integer i) {
//        page.setValue(i);
        startPage.setValue(new Integer(65));
    }

    public void selectCodePoint(int codePoint) {
        Logger.getLogger(UnicodeExplorer.class.getName()).log(
                Level.INFO, "code point " + codePoint);
        ListSelectionModel lsm = codePointTable.getSelectionModel();
        int row = codePoint / codePointColumnWidth;
        lsm.setSelectionInterval(row, row);
        int col = codePoint % codePointColumnWidth;
        codePointTable.setColumnSelectionInterval(col, col);
        codePointTable.scrollRectToVisible(
                codePointTable.getCellRect(row, col, false));
    }

    public void selectFont(Font font) {
        int indexDefault = fontList.indexOf(font);
        fonts.setSelectedIndex(indexDefault);
        Rectangle rect = fonts.getCellBounds(indexDefault, indexDefault);
        if (rect != null) {
            fonts.scrollRectToVisible(rect.getBounds());
        }
    }
}

class FontCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    float fontSize = 24;
    JLabel label;

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {

        Font fontOrig = (Font) value;
        Font temp = fontOrig;
        String pre = "";
        String suf = "";
        int displayIndex = temp.canDisplayUpTo(temp.getFamily());
        if (displayIndex > -1) {
            temp = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, temp.getSize());
            pre = "(";
            suf = ")";
        }

        label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list,
                pre + fontOrig.getFamily() + suf,
                index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        label.setToolTipText(fontOrig.toString());
        label.setFont(temp.deriveFont(fontSize));
        return label;
    }
}

class FontTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private Font displayFont;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel l = (JLabel) c;
            int codePoint = ((Integer) value).intValue();
            boolean isDefined = Character.isDefined(codePoint);
            boolean canDisplay = displayFont.canDisplay(codePoint);
            String s = UnicodeUtil.getCodePointString(codePoint);
            l.setText(s);
            if (displayFont != null) {
                l.setFont(displayFont.deriveFont(
                        (float) (displayFont.getSize() * .8)));
                String tip = "<html><body style='font-size: 64px; "
                        + "font-family: "
                        + displayFont.getFamily()
                        + ";'>&#" + codePoint
                        + " " + Character.getName(codePoint);
                l.setToolTipText(tip);
                l.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                if (!canDisplay) {
                    l.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                if (!isDefined) {
                    l.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Logger.getLogger(
                    UnicodeExplorer.class.getName(),
                    "We are not getting a JLabel as expected!");
        }

        return c;
    }

    public void setDisplayFont(Font font) {
        displayFont = font;
    }
}

class UnicodeUtil {

    public static String getCodePointString(int codePoint) {
        return new String(Character.toChars(codePoint));
    }
}

class CodePointTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
        "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
    };

    public CodePointTableModel(int rows, int cols) {
        super(rows, cols);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return (row * getColumnCount()) + col;
    }
}

class CodePointListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {

        JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        Integer i = (Integer) value;
        String s = new String(
                Character.toChars(i))
                + " - " + Character.getName(i.intValue());
        l.setText(s);

        return l;
    }
}

class FilteredCodePointListModel extends DefaultListModel {

    public String filter = "";
    public Object[] filteredElements = new Object[0];

    public void setFilter(String filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
        filterList();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void filterList() {
        Object[] allElements = super.toArray();
        if (filter.trim().length() == 0) {
            // use entire list.
            filteredElements = allElements;
        } else {
            // filter the list
            ArrayList<Object> allList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            String[] parts = filter.toUpperCase().trim().split(" ");
            for (int ii = 0; ii < super.size(); ii++) {
                Integer codePointInt = (Integer) super.elementAt(ii);
                int codePointNumber = codePointInt.intValue();
                String name = Character.getName(codePointNumber).toUpperCase();
                boolean containsAll = true;
                for (String part : parts) {
                    if (name.indexOf(part) < 0) {
                        containsAll = false;
                    }
                }
                if (containsAll) {
                    allList.add(codePointInt);
                }
            }
            filteredElements = allList.toArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return filteredElements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return filteredElements[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider putting that on GitHub

Comment: @SLaks  If I could figure out Git or SVN, I would.  As it is, I've never successfully created a code repository.  ..must revisit that task soon.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: You can actually do it entirely from their website.  Create a repository, then click Add File.

Comment: @mKorbel  Huh?  You got a stacktrace pointing to line 411?  The search works here.  Though it had some niggling rendering bugs earlier, I thought I'd solved them.  I just retested it and it worked either typing in the combo, or selecting one of the values already defined for it (though it would be nice if typing 'ch' made 'chess' be highlit immediately below in the drop-down..).

Comment: @SLaks  OK thanks.  Never saw an 'Add File' button but found the (tiny) `+` symbol to do the same thing.  UGlys now (theoretically) available at https://github.com/andrewthommo/UGlys :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson still caused me, I'll to test again, exception caused only in the case that there isn't any matches in JComboBox  v.s. JList

Comment: @mKorbel Oh right..  I had not tested that aspect much.  Perhaps I should give it a run at Code Review, but I should tidy the code some first (it is not so much 'software engineered' as 'held together with chewing gum and old shoelaces - with strips of duck tape on the really doubtful bits').  See also the [Code Repository](https://github.com/andrewthommo/UGlys) at GitHub.  Feel free to establish a branch if you want to get right into it..  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson please to see my deleted post here, now I'm too lazy to test in WinXP (multi_boot WinXP - Win7 - Win8)

Comment: @mKorbel  Thanks for the report.  :)  I'll look into it.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thank you for your effort, very nice code, will be important for repeated questions like .... `why I can't display Xxxx chars/Language in Java (Swing, JDBC, (J)Applet)`