# How to Display Unicode Characters in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, unicode

**Problem**: I have java code that i would like to display a Unicode  character like the following capture image. I succeed to display in `System.out.println` but in java swing I could not display the character.

**Question**: How can I display the Unicode character in JTextPane so I can see the emotions?

[image: Capture Image]

**Code**:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf("\u2622"));
    textPane.setContentType("text/html");
    textPane.setText("c'est " + String.valueOf("\u2622"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Post pictures _and_ code, not pictures _of_ code.

Comment: Be sure to use a `Font` that can display the character of interest! For that you might use `font.canDisplay(codePoint)` as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18858313/418556).

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine, as far as I can tell, you just need to `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` in the last lines:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf("\u2622"));
    textPane.setContentType("text/html");
    textPane.setText("c'est " + String.valueOf("\u2622"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();            // Add these
    frame.setVisible(true);  // two lines
}
```

This should display the JTextPane as you expected.

Comment: Sorry ,
I appreciate your help  but i added your  2 lines but i steel not solve my problem so i would like to display the  caratere Unicode ☢ =\u2622  in jtextpane not like show me this caractere □ in the jtextpane. That is the caractere unknow when it display like this □.
Cordially

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to try and help you. Try changing the line with `setContentType` to `textPane.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: Thank you it work but when i try another caractere Unicode like this = \u1F604 they don't show me the result. It seems like that □4. So i tried to change UTF-8 to UTF-16 but steel not work. How can i solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to get those unicode characters. You probably should ask that on a new question