# How to determine font size for certain height of area in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, graphics2d

I want to calculate font size by having height (in px) of area in which single char is drawn.

To draw a char I use :

```
g2.drawString(value, startX, startY );
```

How can I determine font size for specific height?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do it.  I generally get a `Shape` from the `GlyphVector`.  E.G. as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18686753/418556)..

Comment: Also consider `g2.getFontMetrics()` or `TextLayout`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20textLayout).