# Can't get the reason of the exception. Can anyone give me the clue? Where is the null there?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

```
static JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();

static char cell[][][] = new char[2][12][12];
static JButton jCell[][][] = new JButton[2][12][12];
public void initField(){
    for (int y=1; y<11; y++){
        for (int field=0; field<2; field++ ){
            for (int x=1; x<11; x++){
                cell[field][x][y] = '.';
                jCell[field][x][y].setBounds((x * 20) + (field * 200), y * 20, 15, 15);
                fieldPanel.add(jCell[field][x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in the longest string/

Comment: You haven't initialized the 1st and 2nd dimensions of `cell` and none of `jCell`.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).  That code seems better suited to a `GridLayout`, e.g. as seen in [Making a robust, resizable Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create JButton like below and then you can set the bounds.

```
jCell[field][x][y] = new JButton();
jCell[field][x][y].setBounds((x * 20) + (field * 200), y * 20, 15, 15);
```

Comment: They (preferred size and bounds) are both terrible suggestions.  See See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556) as well as the answer linked in my first comment above.

Answer (score 0):

`jCell[field][x][y]` is `null` just before you call `jCell[field][x][y].setBounds()`, hence the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

`static JButton jCell[][][] = new JButton[2][12][12];` just create the 3D array of references to `JButton`s but :

- no `JButton` is created
- array is filled with `null`

Then when you call `jCell[field][x][y].whatYouWant` you try to dereference `null`.

Initialize your `jCell` array with buttons :

```
for (i=0; ...
  for (j=0; ...
    for (k=0; ...
      jCell[i][j][k] = new JButton(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type[] var = new Type[2];
```

will only allocate space in memory to hold 2 Type objects and initialize each entry to `null`. This means that:

```
var[0] == null
```

evaluates to `true` after that.

Thus

```
var[0].method();
```

throws a `NullPointerException`.

You need to initialize each entry of your array before you can deference them:

```
jCell[field][x][y] = new JButton(...);
jCell[field][x][y].setBounds(...);
```

or:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setBounds(...);
jCell[field][x][y] = button;
```