# Is it possible to maintain a transparent background in an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing, transparency, imageicon

I am making chess in Java and I have a board with black and white squares of JButtons. So basically my code is something like this:

```
JButton[][] board = new JButton[8][8];
JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel();
boardPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        board[row][col] = new JButton("");
        board[row][col].setBackground(new Color(70, 70, 70));
        boardPanel.add(board[row][col]);
    }
}
```

On the buttons I will have the respective chess pieces. I have them created with a transparent background so they will show on either the black or white squares. When I add them to the buttons, the transparency goes away for but .jpg and .png formats. How can I fix this? Every image is in the following format:

```
ImageIcon whitePawn = new ImageIcon("whitePawn.jpg");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a problem with images becoming non-transparent or with buttons being non-transparent?

Comment: See [Making a robust, resizable Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142686/making-a-robust-resizable-chess-gui) for a Chess GUI that uses images with transparency (around each chess piece) to show the black/white are behind the bounds of the painted image.  The image uses PNG for transparency, though you might also use GIF.  JPEG simply does not support transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPG does not support transparency. You can use proper PNG files.

There are a few alternative ways though:

1. You can create 2 images for each piece e.g whitePawnInWhiteCell.jpg and whitePawnInBlackCell.jpg and use them.
2. You can define Shape for each piece and apply appropriate clip before drawing the image on cell.