# Java - How to force buttons to bottom of panel after others have been removed?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton, keylistener

I'm making a very simple game in Java where when you press a button on your keyboard, the corresponding button is removed, however I want the buttons to all be pushed to the bottom accordingly when one is removed. I'm not sure where I should do this in the code or what method to use. Is there a way to sort of pack the frame so that everything is anchored to the bottom?

Here is a picture of the program when it is ran:

[image]

And when I press the 3rd button, I want the blocks above it to fall down on top of the rest (similar to other falling block games).

[image]

```
public class Game implements Runnable, KeyListener {

JFrame _frame = new JFrame("Window");
JPanel _pan = new JPanel();


Character[] buttonsToAdd = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
List<Character> shuffled = Arrays.asList(buttonsToAdd);     
Map<Character, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<Character, JButton>();

@Override
public void run() {

    _frame.add(_pan);
    _frame.setVisible(true);
    _pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(buttonsToAdd.length, 0));

    for (char c : buttonsToAdd) {
        JButton button = new JButton(c + "");
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        _pan.add(button);
        buttons.put(c, button);
        button.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    _frame.pack();
    _frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    _frame.setResizable(true);


}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    char key = e.getKeyChar();
    System.out.println(key);
    JButton button = null;

    if ((button = buttons.get(Character.toUpperCase(key))) != null) {
        _pan.remove(button);
        _pan.invalidate();
        _frame.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

}
```

Also, I set the buttons to randomize which letters are used (A-D) but if there are for example, two A buttons, I can only make one removed and pressing A again doesn't remove another. How can I remove both A buttons when A is pressed?

I've been struggling with this for a while, any help would be super appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a BoxLayout.

```
Box box = new Box.createVerticalBox();
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
box.add( button1 );
box.add( button2 );
...
```

The "glue" will expand as more space is available in the panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

Also, don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33809134/131872 for a working example using this approach.