# How to draw a random color from a color array list and apply it to the backgrounds of buttons from another array list?

Tags: java, arrays, colors

```
Character[] buttonsToAdd = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
List<Character> shuffled = Arrays.asList(buttonsToAdd);
Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW};
Map<Character, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<Character, JButton>();
Map<Color, JButton> col = new HashMap<Color, JButton>();
```

I have these array lists for the letters of the alphabet and 4 colors. I want to randomly select only 4 letters from the letter array list, apply them to 4 buttons, and then assign those 4 buttons each a random color from the color array list. How would I go about doing this?

I've tried using random and then using setBackground on my buttons in my for statement, but it doesn't allow me to reference the 'colors' array list that way.

```
for (char c : buttonsToAdd) {

        JButton button = new JButton(c + "");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        button.setBackground(new Color(rnd.nextInt(colors)));
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        _pan.add(button);
        buttons.put(c, button);
        button.addKeyListener(this);

    }
```

I'm still new to Java, is there an easy way to both limit the amount of characters assigned to buttons from the 'ButtonsToAdd' list to 4, as well as assigning each one a random color from the color list?

```
public class Game implements Runnable, KeyListener {

JFrame _frame = new JFrame("Window");
JPanel _pan = new JPanel();

Character[] buttonsToAdd = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q',
        'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

Map<Character, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<Character, JButton>();
List<Character> shuffled = Arrays.asList(buttonsToAdd);
Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW };
Map<Color, JButton> col = new HashMap<Color, JButton>();
List<Character> shuffledCharacters = Arrays.asList(buttonsToAdd);

@Override

public void run() {

    _frame.add(_pan);
    _frame.setVisible(true);
    _pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

    for (char c : buttonsToAdd) {

        JButton button = new JButton(c + "");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        button.setBackground(colors[rnd.nextInt(colors.length)]);
        _pan.add(button);
        buttons.put(c, button);
        button.addKeyListener(this);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledCharacters);

    }

    _frame.pack();
    _frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    _frame.setResizable(true);

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    char key = e.getKeyChar();
    System.out.println(key);
    JButton button = null;

    if ((button = buttons.get(Character.toUpperCase(key))) != null) {
        _pan.remove(button);
        _pan.invalidate();
        _frame.repaint();

    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you still using a KeyListener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850349/java-how-to-force-buttons-to-bottom-of-panel-after-others-have-been-removed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to break your requirements down...

First you need to build the button for each character...

```
Character[] buttonsToAdd = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

Map<Character, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<Character, JButton>();
for (Character c : buttonsToAdd) {
    buttons.put(c, new JButton(c.toString()));
}
```

Then you need shuffle/randomise the color and characters

```
Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW};

List<Color> shuffledColors = Arrays.asList(colors);
List<Character> shuffledCharacters = Arrays.asList(buttonsToAdd);

Collections.shuffle(shuffledColors);
Collections.shuffle(shuffledCharacters);
```

Then you need to map the color with the button, but you need the `character` as the key to get the button...

```
Map<Color, JButton> col = new HashMap<Color, JButton>();
for (int index = 0; index < shuffledColors.size(); index++) {
    Color color = shuffledColors.get(index);
    Character c = shuffledCharacters.get(index);

    JButton btn = buttons.get(c);

    col.put(color, btn);
}
```

**Updated**

So based on your updated requirements, your current approach won't work, as you need all your buttons to have one of the available colors, but your `Map<Color, JButton>` will only allow a single button to be associated with a single color.

Instead, you might need to do something more like...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }

    public Game() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<String> characters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}));
        private List<JButton> buttons;
        private List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW}));

        private Map<String, JButton> characterToButton = new HashMap<>(25);
        private Map<Color, List<JButton>> colorToButtons = new HashMap<>(25);

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

            List<Integer> indicies = new ArrayList<>(4 * 4);
            buttons = new ArrayList<>(25);
            for (int index = 0; index < 4 * 4; index++) {
                Collections.shuffle(colors);
                Color color = colors.get(0);
                indicies.add(index);
                JButton btn = new JButton();
                buttons.add(btn);
                btn.setBackground(color);
                add(btn);

                List<JButton> btns = colorToButtons.get(color);
                if (btns == null) {
                    btns = new ArrayList<>(25);
                    colorToButtons.put(color, btns);
                }
                btns.add(btn);
            }

            Collections.shuffle(characters);
            Collections.shuffle(indicies);
            List<Color> usedColor = new ArrayList<>(4);
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                String value = characters.get(index);
                JButton btn = null;
                do {
                    int buttonIndex = indicies.remove(0);
                    btn = buttons.get(buttonIndex);
                } while (usedColor.contains(btn.getBackground()));
                usedColor.add(btn.getBackground());
                btn.setText(value);
                characterToButton.put(value, btn);
                addKeyBinding(btn, value);
            }
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(JComponent comp, String value) {
            InputMap inputMap = comp.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = comp.getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("typed " + value.toLowerCase()), value);
            actionMap.put(value, new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JButton btn = characterToButton.get(value);
                    Color color = btn.getBackground();
                    for (JButton others : colorToButtons.get(color)) {
                        others.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I'm not getting any buttons showing at all while implementing these.

Comment: Well, since you've not provided any code which shows how you're using the buttons, I'm not sure how I can help

Comment: I apologize you're right. I've edited the original post to contain the entirety of my code. Basically I'm randomizing 4 letters of the alphabet, and  applying those 4 letters to 4 buttons on a 4x4 grid. While only 4 buttons have letters on them, all 16 are suppose to have colors. And when I press a button, the corresponding letter is removed along with any other buttons of the same color. So far I'm still in the somewhat beginning stages.

Comment: Okay, problem #1 `Map<Color, JButton> col = new HashMap<Color, JButton>();` will only allow a single button to be associated with a single color

Comment: Wow I didn't expect this! Thank you so much I'm gonna have to go through and figure out what you did and try writing it myself (trying to learn after all). But thank you it looks 1000x better than mine did!

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setBackground(new Color(rnd.nextInt(colors)));
```

Nope. Yes, you can pass an int into the Color constructor, but you're not going to get the color you expected. But not only that, this line won't compile since the `Random#nextInt(...)` won't accept a Color array as its parameter. An int, yes, such as `colors.length`, but not the array itself.

Instead try

```
Random rnd = new Random();


// and elsewhere
int randomIndex = rnd.nextInt(colors.length);
button.setBackground(colors[randomIndex]);
```

Or if you insist on compressing your code,

```
button.setBackground(colors[rnd.nextInt(colors.length)]);
```

Note, since colors appears to be a constant, it should be re-named COLORS, and declared thusly:

```
Color[] COLORS = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW};
```

since per Java naming conventions, constants should be all-upper case.