# Can it be possible to set coordinates in Image / ImageIcon / ImageIO on java?

Tags: java, image, character

I try to make a character like in games and his movement in one big image and he have a lot of movement. Can it be possible to set coordinates on the image or do I have to cut the image and put every image one by one?

Comment: There are at least 2 ways. One way by using JLabels and move the labels but I do not recommend doing that if you were planning to create a game in Java. The other way is to use custom painting. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711891/how-to-create-a-background-and-foreground-image-which-overlaps/35711894#35711894

Comment: Thanks for answering but
I dont means to that what I means is if I have an image with alot of movments can I set X and Y on the image and dont cut alon every movment that the character has?