# Putting an JPanel into the foreground within another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to create a small drag and drop program in Java.
It is supposed to be a "fist contact to programing", like taking some components of code with the mouse and move them into a loop (while, do while, for). This should be shown grafically. 
I have a JFrame, with a JPanel in it (absolut layout for my panel) and I add two (later there will be some panels more but at the moment unimportant) more JPanels to my panel (colored them to see which one is in front). So I found out that the first JPanel which is added to my mainpanel is in the foreground. I wrote a working method to put a JPanel into the foreground but I want to know if there is another, maybe "easyier" way to move a JPanel to the foreground.

Here is the code of my new class containing my written method:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ForegroundJPanel
  extends JPanel {

  public void setToForeground(JPanel foregroundPanel, JPanel backgroundPanel, JPanel container)
  {
    container.remove(backgroundPanel);
    container.remove(foregroundPanel);
    container.validate();
    container.add(foregroundPanel);
    container.add(backgroundPanel);
    container.validate();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To make it more clearly what I mean: [See the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf44a.jpg)

Comment: I think question is more appropriate for code review.

Comment: @HSV_DO You can consider using custom painting which could be easier than directly dealing with multiple panels: [Foreground & background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711891/how-to-create-a-background-and-foreground-image-which-overlaps/35711894#35711894)

Comment: These guys made some [draggable components](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116088/Draggable-Components-in-Java-Swing).

Comment: A lot will depend on the layout manager, but you could use [`Container#setComponentZOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder(java.awt.Component,%20int)) or [`OverlayLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html) or [`JLayeredPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: @user3437460 I guess You can't move a directly drawn part anymore or am I wrong at this point?

Comment: @matt Thanks that looks good, I'll check how they have done their program

Comment: @HSV_DO Do You mean can we drag and drop using custom painting?

Comment: @user3437460 I reckon that it would not be possible to drag and drop a custom painting but I'm not sure about that at all..