# How to create this grid-like layout with column and row labels?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BattleShip {

    private static ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon("cols.png"); 
    private static ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon("rows.png");
    private static JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    private static JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private static JButton[][] button = new JButton[10][10];
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("BattleShip");
    private static JButton open;

    public static void fileMenu() {

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
        open.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));

        JMenuItem restartGame = new JMenuItem("Restart Game");
        restartGame.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        restartGame.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));

        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));

        open.addActionListener(new OpenMenu());
        exit.addActionListener(new ExitMenu()); 

        fileMenu.add(open);
        fileMenu.add(restartGame);
        fileMenu.add(exit);

        menubar.add(fileMenu);

    }

    public static void layout() {


        JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();

        JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel cpuPanel = new JPanel();

        panelOne.add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panelOne.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelTwo.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelOne.add(new JLabel(image1), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelTwo.add(new JLabel(image1), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panelOne.add(new JLabel(image2), BorderLayout.WEST);
        panelTwo.add(new JLabel(image2), BorderLayout.WEST);




        panelOne.add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        container.add(panelOne);
        container.add(panelTwo);        
    }

    public static void FlowLayout() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        JPanel playerSide = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));



        JLabel cols = new JLabel();
        cols.setIcon(image1);
        JLabel rows = new JLabel();
        rows.setIcon(image2);


        panel.add(cols);


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        fileMenu();
        layout();








        frame.add(container);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar); 

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static class ExitMenu implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    private static class OpenMenu implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        }
    }
    private static class SelectFile implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == open) {


            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this layout with the rows and cols as a picture?
For the cols how would i do the white space and combine the two together and make a grid? None of the other questions shows me how to do this layout?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).

Answer (score 2):

Shoot, I made something just like that that I'll try to dig out....

Made a long while ago and used two jpg images to create a GUI like so:

[image]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BattleShipMainProg {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      BattleShipMainPanel mainPanel;
      try {
         mainPanel = new BattleShipMainPanel();
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battleship");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         frame.setVisible(true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BattleShipMainPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int TA_ROWS = 10;
   private static final int TA_COLS = 30;
   private static final int CELL_SIDE_LENGTH = 36;
   private static final String WEST_IMG_PATH = "battleship/images/Wallpaper-Picture-Under-Water Crp.jpg";
   private static final String EAST_IMG_PATH = "battleship/images/Maldives_Sml.jpg";
   private BattleShipGridPanel playerGrid;
   private BattleShipGridPanel opponentGrid;
   private ShipImageMaker imageMaker = new ShipImageMaker(CELL_SIDE_LENGTH);
   private JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);

   public BattleShipMainPanel() throws IOException {
      ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
      System.out.println(classLoader.getResource("").getFile());
      String westImgString = WEST_IMG_PATH;
      String eastImgString = EAST_IMG_PATH;
      BufferedImage westImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource(westImgString));
      BufferedImage eastImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource(eastImgString));

      playerGrid = new BattleShipGridPanel(westImg, CELL_SIDE_LENGTH);
      opponentGrid = new BattleShipGridPanel(eastImg, CELL_SIDE_LENGTH);

      // !! to delete
      playerGrid.getLabel("A 1").setIcon(imageMaker.getSternLeftIcon()[0]);
      playerGrid.getLabel("A 2").setIcon(imageMaker.getMidshipHorizIcon()[0]);
      playerGrid.getLabel("A 3").setIcon(imageMaker.getMidshipHorizIcon()[0]);
      playerGrid.getLabel("A 4").setIcon(imageMaker.getMidshipHorizIcon()[0]);
      playerGrid.getLabel("A 5").setIcon(imageMaker.getBowRightIcon()[0]);

      playerGrid.getLabel("C 2").setIcon(imageMaker.getBowUpIcon()[1]);
      playerGrid.getLabel("D 2").setIcon(imageMaker.getMidshipVertIcon()[1]);
      playerGrid.getLabel("E 2").setIcon(imageMaker.getSternDownIcon()[1]);
      // !! to delete

      playerGrid.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pChngEvt) {
            if (pChngEvt.getPropertyName().equals(
                  BattleShipGridPanel.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
               textarea.append("Player: " + pChngEvt.getNewValue() + "\n");

               System.out.printf("[%c, %d]%n", playerGrid.getSelectedRow(), playerGrid.getSelectedCol());
               playerGrid.resetSelections();
            }
         }
      });

      opponentGrid.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pChngEvt) {
            if (pChngEvt.getPropertyName().equals(
                  BattleShipGridPanel.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
               textarea.append("Opponent: " + pChngEvt.getNewValue() + "\n");
               opponentGrid.resetSelections();
            }
         }
      });

      textarea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
      textarea.setEditable(false);
      textarea.setFocusable(false);

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
      centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      JPanel centerTopPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      centerTopPanel.add(new JLabel("GridCell Pressed", SwingConstants.LEFT),
            BorderLayout.NORTH);
      centerTopPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textarea,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER));
      centerPanel.add(centerTopPanel);
      centerPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

      JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      playerPanel.add(new JLabel("Player", JLabel.LEFT),
            BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      playerPanel.add(playerGrid.getMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      JPanel opponentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      opponentPanel.add(new JLabel("Opponent", JLabel.LEFT),
            BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      opponentPanel.add(opponentGrid.getMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      int eb = 10;
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(eb, eb, eb, eb));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(eb, eb));
      add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(opponentPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BattleShipGridPanel {
   public static final String MOUSE_PRESSED = "Mouse Pressed";
   // public static final String MOUSE_DRAGGED = "Mouse Dragged";
   private static final int ROW_COUNT = 11;
   private static final int COL_COUNT = 11;

   // the main JPanel for this part of my program
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(){
      // it draws an image if available
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         myPaint(g);
      };
   };
   private Image img = null;
   private String selectedCellName = "";
   private JLabel selectedLabel = null;
   private Map<String, JLabel> labelMap = new HashMap<String, JLabel>();
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport propChangeSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);

   public BattleShipGridPanel(Image img, int cellSideLength) {
      this.img = img;
      mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 11));
      mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      mainPanel.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);

      for (int row = 0; row < ROW_COUNT; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < COL_COUNT; col++) {
            String rowStr = String.valueOf((char) ('A' + row - 1));
            String colStr = String.valueOf(col);
            String name = ""; // name for component
            String text = ""; // text to display

            // create JLabel to add to grid
            JLabel label = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);

            // text to display if label is a row header at col 0
            if (col == 0 && row != 0) {
               text = "" + rowStr;
            } else

            // text to display if label is a col header at row 0
            if (row == 0 && col != 0) {
               text = "" + colStr;
            } else

            // name to give to label if label is on the grid and not a
            // row or col header
            if (row != 0 && col != 0) {
               name = rowStr + " " + colStr;
               labelMap.put(name, label);
            }
            label.setText(text);
            label.setName(name);
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cellSideLength, cellSideLength));
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            mainPanel.add(label);
         }
      }
   }

   private void myPaint(Graphics g) {
      if (img != null) {
         int w0 = mainPanel.getWidth();
         int h0 = mainPanel.getHeight();
         int x = w0 / 11;
         int y = h0 / 11;

         int iW = img.getWidth(null);
         int iH = img.getHeight(null);

         g.drawImage(img, x, y, w0, h0, 0, 0, iW, iH, null);
      }
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      propChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         if (mEvt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            Component comp = mainPanel.getComponentAt(mEvt.getPoint());
            if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
               String name = comp.getName();
               if (!name.trim().isEmpty()) {
                  String oldValue = selectedCellName;
                  String newValue = name;
                  selectedCellName = name;
                  selectedLabel = (JLabel) comp;
                  propChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(MOUSE_PRESSED, oldValue, newValue);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public JPanel getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public String getSelectedCellName() {
      return selectedCellName;
   }

   public char getSelectedRow() {
      if (selectedCellName.isEmpty()) {
         return (char)0;
      } else {
         return selectedCellName.split(" ")[0].charAt(0);
      }
   }

   public int getSelectedCol() {
      if (selectedCellName.isEmpty()) {
         return 0;
      } else {
         return Integer.parseInt(selectedCellName.split(" ")[1]);
      }
   }

   public JLabel getSelectedLabel() {
      return selectedLabel;
   }

   public void resetSelections() {
      selectedCellName = "";
      selectedLabel = null;
   }

   public JLabel getLabel(String key) {
      return labelMap.get(key);
   }

   public void resetAll() {
      resetSelections();
      for (String key : labelMap.keySet()) {
         labelMap.get(key).setIcon(null);
      }
   }

   // for testing purposes only
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      // path to some undersea image
      String imgPath = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"
            + "commons/3/31/Great_white_shark_south_africa.jpg";
      BufferedImage img = null;
      try {
         img = ImageIO.read(new URL(imgPath));
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      int cellSideLength = 36;
      BattleShipGridPanel gridPanel = new BattleShipGridPanel(img, cellSideLength);
      gridPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            // print out where the mouse pressed:
            System.out.println(evt.getNewValue());
         }
      });
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BattleShipGridPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(gridPanel.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ShipImageMaker {
   public static final double GAP = 1.0 / 10.0;
   public static final Color LINE_COLOR = Color.black;
   public static final Color[] SHIP_FILL_COLOR = { // Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
         new Color(200, 200, 200, 180),
         new Color(255, 100, 100, 180) };
   public static final Color SHIP_BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
   private AffineTransform rotateUp;
   private ImageIcon[] bowRightIcon = new ImageIcon[2];
   private ImageIcon[] bowUpIcon = new ImageIcon[2];
   private ImageIcon[] sternLeftIcon = new ImageIcon[2];
   private ImageIcon[] sternDownIcon = new ImageIcon[2];
   private ImageIcon[] midshipHorizIcon = new ImageIcon[2];
   private ImageIcon[] midshipVertIcon = new ImageIcon[2];

   public ShipImageMaker(int side) {
      rotateUp = AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(3, side / 2,
            side / 2);

      Path2D turretPath = new Path2D.Double();
      double tpX = side / 2.0 - 3 * GAP * side;
      double tpY = side / 2.0 - 1.5 * GAP * side;
      double tpW = 3 * GAP * side;
      double tpH = tpW;
      double lx1 = tpX + tpW;
      double ly1 = side / 2.0 - 0.5 * GAP * side;
      double lx2 = lx1 + 1.5 * GAP * side;
      double ly2 = ly1;
      turretPath.append(new Ellipse2D.Double(tpX, tpY, tpW, tpH), false);
      turretPath.append(new Line2D.Double(lx1, ly1, lx2, ly2), false);
      turretPath.append(new Line2D.Double(lx1, side - ly1, lx2, side - ly2),
            false);

      double y1 = GAP * side;
      double ctrlx = side / 2.0;
      double ctrly = y1;
      double x2 = side - y1;
      double y2 = side / 2.0;

      QuadCurve2D topQC = new QuadCurve2D.Double(0, y1, ctrlx, ctrly, x2, y2);
      QuadCurve2D botQC = new QuadCurve2D.Double(x2, y2, ctrlx, side - ctrly,
            0, side - y1);
      Path2D bowFillPath = new Path2D.Double();
      bowFillPath.moveTo(0, y1);
      bowFillPath.append(topQC, false);
      bowFillPath.append(botQC, false);
      bowFillPath.lineTo(0, y1);

      Path2D bowDrawPath = new Path2D.Double();
      bowDrawPath.append(topQC, false);
      bowDrawPath.append(botQC, false);
      bowDrawPath.append(turretPath, false);

      Line2D midShipTopLine = new Line2D.Double(0, y1, side, y1);
      Line2D midShipBotLine = new Line2D.Double(side, side - y1, 0, side - y1);
      Path2D midShipFillPath = new Path2D.Double();
      midShipFillPath.moveTo(0, y1);
      midShipFillPath.append(midShipTopLine, false);
      midShipFillPath.lineTo(side, side - y1);
      midShipFillPath.append(midShipBotLine, false);
      midShipFillPath.lineTo(0, y1);

      Path2D midShipDrawPath = new Path2D.Double();
      midShipDrawPath.append(midShipTopLine, false);
      midShipDrawPath.append(midShipBotLine, false);
      midShipDrawPath.append(turretPath, false);

      Path2D sternDrawPath = new Path2D.Double();
      sternDrawPath.moveTo(side, y1);
      sternDrawPath.lineTo(side / 2, y1);
      sternDrawPath.append(new CubicCurve2D.Double(side / 2, y1, y1, y1, y1,
            side - y1, side / 2, side - y1), false);
      sternDrawPath.lineTo(side, side - y1);

      Path2D sternFillPath = new Path2D.Double(sternDrawPath);
      sternFillPath.lineTo(side, y1);

      sternDrawPath.append(turretPath.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform
            .getQuadrantRotateInstance(2, side / 2, side / 2)), false);

      for (int i = 0; i < bowRightIcon.length; i++) {
         BufferedImage img = createImage(side, bowFillPath, bowDrawPath,
               SHIP_FILL_COLOR[i]);
         bowRightIcon[i] = new ImageIcon(img);
         bowUpIcon[i] = rotateUp(side, img);

         img = createImage(side, midShipFillPath, midShipDrawPath,
               SHIP_FILL_COLOR[i]);
         midshipHorizIcon[i] = new ImageIcon(img);
         midshipVertIcon[i] = rotateUp(side, img);

         img = createImage(side, sternFillPath, sternDrawPath,
               SHIP_FILL_COLOR[i]);
         sternLeftIcon[i] = new ImageIcon(img);
         sternDownIcon[i] = rotateUp(side, img);
      }

   }

   private BufferedImage createImage(int side, Path2D fillPath,
         Path2D drawPath, Color shipFillColor) {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(side, side,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(shipFillColor);
      g2.setBackground(SHIP_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
      g2.fill(fillPath);
      g2.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
      g2.draw(drawPath);
      g2.dispose();
      return img;
   }

   private ImageIcon rotateUp(int side, BufferedImage src) {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(side, side,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setTransform(rotateUp);
      g2.drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);
      g2.dispose();
      return new ImageIcon(img);
   }

   public ImageIcon[] getBowRightIcon() {
      return bowRightIcon;
   }

   public ImageIcon[] getBowUpIcon() {
      return bowUpIcon;
   }

   public ImageIcon[] getSternLeftIcon() {
      return sternLeftIcon;
   }

   public ImageIcon[] getSternDownIcon() {
      return sternDownIcon;
   }

   public ImageIcon[] getMidshipHorizIcon() {
      return midshipHorizIcon;
   }

   public ImageIcon[] getMidshipVertIcon() {
      return midshipVertIcon;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Icon> icons = new ArrayList<Icon>();
      ShipImageMaker imgMaker = new ShipImageMaker(40);

      icons.add(imgMaker.getBowRightIcon()[0]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getBowRightIcon()[1]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getBowUpIcon()[0]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getBowUpIcon()[1]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getMidshipHorizIcon()[0]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getMidshipHorizIcon()[1]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getMidshipVertIcon()[0]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getMidshipVertIcon()[1]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getSternDownIcon()[0]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getSternDownIcon()[1]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getSternLeftIcon()[0]);
      icons.add(imgMaker.getSternLeftIcon()[1]);

      for (Icon icon : icons) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(icon));
      }
   }
}
```

Used BorderLayout, GridLayout and BoxLayout.

Comment: @credirs123: the bottom line: each grid uses GridLayout, and the overall GUI would use BoxLayout configured using BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS

Answer (score 2):

A lot will come down to what it is you want to achieve, for example you could use a `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout` or a combination of layout managers or you could use custom painting or you could use a `JTable` for example...

[image: Layout]

Now, this is pretty basic and is only intended to provide a proof of concept

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(10, 10);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setRowHeight(40);
            table.setShowGrid(true);
            table.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);

            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
            sp.setRowHeaderView(new RowHeader(table));
            add(sp);
        }

    }

    public class RowHeader extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;

        public RowHeader(JTable table) {
            setOpaque(false);
            this.table = table;
            table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
                @Override
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                    prepareLayout();
                }
            });
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            prepareLayout();
        }

        protected void prepareLayout() {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            Border border = new MatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
                char value = (char) ('A' + row);
                JLabel label = makeLabel(Character.toString(value));
                label.setBorder(border);
                add(label, gbc);
            }
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            JLabel filler = makeLabel("");
            filler.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
            add(filler, gbc);
        }

        protected JLabel makeLabel(String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text) {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
                    size.height = table.getRowHeight();
                    size.width += 10;
                    return size;
                }
            };
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            return label;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: for the abc and 0123 how would i be able to use the images provided

Comment: Why? Okay, yes, but you'd need to split the images down into individual subimages so you can supply each one to each header cell, but why? You could accomplish the same thing by just using labels and customising the fonts

Answer (score 0):

Use BorderLayout, take 3 panel and set them in NORTH, CENTER and SOUTH. IN CENTER use  JTable. to diaplay your table and if you want to add the alphabet also between two tables you can split your center panel by adding sub panels in the center panel. 
like center_panel.add(subpanel1, and your desire location), or simply go through flow layout.

Comment: My image is not displaying

Comment: Nothing is displaying when i put that