# GridBagLayout stacks labels when using custom subclass from Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I am writing a GUI with Swing. I'm using a `GridBagLayout` to display multiple `JLabels` in a grid (basically like a chess board). As soon as I use a self made label class derived from `JLabel` instead of `JLabel`, the `GridBagLayout` stacks every label on the top left corner of the `JPanel`.

Either my subclass `TileLabel` is incorrect or I don't use the layout and constraints the right way. I think the last one because I can't see what would be a problem in such a minimal subclass.

This is how it looks using `JLabel` (L represents a label):

```
(MenuBar)
L L L L L L L L L
L L L L L L L L L
L L L L L L L L L
```

This is how it looks using `TileLabel` (S represents all the labels stacked):

```
(MenuBar)
S
```

This is my simple subclass from JLabel:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TileLabel extends JLabel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6718776819945522562L;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public TileLabel(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

And this is the GUI class. I Marked the three lines where I used my custom label which lead to the layout problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainGUI extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8750891542665009043L;
    private JFrame frame;
    private MainMenuBar menuBar;
    private TileLabel[][] labelGrid; // <-- LINE 1
    private GridBagConstraints constraints;
    private int gridWidth;
    private int gridHeight;

     // Basic constructor.
    public MainGUI(int frameWidth, int frameHeight) {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        buildFrame(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        buildLabelGrid(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    }

    // Builds the frame.
    private void buildFrame(int frameWidth, int frameHeight) {
        menuBar = new MainMenuBar();
        frame = new JFrame("Carcasonne");
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new Color(165, 200, 245));
    }

    // Creates the grid of labels.
    private void buildLabelGrid(int frameWidth, int frameHeight) {
        gridWidth = frameWidth / 100;
        gridHeight = frameHeight / 100;
        labelGrid = new TileLabel[gridWidth][gridHeight]; // <-- LINE 2
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++) {
                labelGrid[x][y] = new TileLabel(x, y); // <-- LINE 3
                constraints.gridx = x;
                constraints.gridy = y;
                add(labelGrid[x][y], constraints); // add label with constraints
            }
        }
    }

    // sets the icon of a specific label
    public void paint(Tile tile, int x, int y) {
        if (x >= 0 && x < gridWidth && y >= 0 && y < gridHeight) {
            labelGrid[x][y].setIcon(tile.getImage());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid label grid position (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        }
    }

    // Just to test this GUI:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainGUI gui = new MainGUI(1280, 768);
        Tile tile = TileFactory.createTile(TileType.Road);
        for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
                gui.paint(tile, x, x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: *"basically like a chess board"* See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556) for tips on layout and components to use (e.g. a `JButton` instead of a `JLabel` for each grid square).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Override]

You have accidentally overridden [`JComponent#getX()` and `JComponent#getY()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getX--). The values returned by this method are **not** consistent with the values that the layout may set internally (via calls to `setBounds` or so). This messes up the layout.

<sub>(Admittedly, I did not really *check* whether this is the reason, but it likely is, and it is a problem in general!)</sub>

Comment: That was the problem. I generated the getters with my IDE and did not realize that i overrode these methods. Thanks fo the help.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few things to fix in your code, but your problem originates from 3 things:

1. Your method definitions in your custom label:

   ```
   public class TileLabel extends JLabel {

       // @Override !!!!
       public int getX() {
           return x;
       }

       // @Override !!!!
       public int getY() {
           return y;
       }
   }
   ```

   You are overriding `JComponent`'s `getX()` and `getY()`, which are responsible for returning their coordinates. This messes up the layout completely.

   Be careful with your `paint` method, a method with the same name exists in a superclass, though you are saved in this case since the arguments are different.
2. You have a typo at your loop: `gui.paint(tile, x, x)` should be `gui.paint(tile, x, y)`.
3. The order in which you call your methods is wrong. First, you create the frame and display it, then you change its contents by adding the panel with the labels to it, then you change the text in the labels. You should do this the other way around.

My recommendations:

- Make your `paint` method be made a member of your `TileLabel` class. It makes more sense.
- Set the icons during creation of the labels, unless they are not known. If you can't, you might need to recalculate the space requirements.
- Never make your layout dependent on the size of the screen or its resolution. It makes for a fragile GUI (as noted in the comments). Use `pack()` for the frame to calculate the correct size.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks fo the help and the additional tips.

Comment: @ConveniencePatterns Well, you had more than 1 :) By the way, your GUI doesn't work for me because the size is too large and it overflows my screen. See my recommendations and if you need help I can post some code.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Problem 2 occurred when I shortened my code for stack overflow. Problem 3 is definitely a design mistake I will fix ASAP. Do you mean it overflows because its fixed size? Making the GUI size dynamic is on my TODO list.

Comment: @ConveniencePatterns Yes, it's too large and can't be resized. Allow it to be resized and use `pack()` instead of `setSize(...)`. That's all you need to do. Make sure the order is `pack`, `seLocationRelativeTo` and then `setVisible`.

Comment: When using `pack()` to resize the GUI, I need the maximal size the frame could possibly have. The grid size should be maximal in height and width for every resolution and tiles of size 100x100 (See method `buildLabelGrid()`). I don't need the resolution, I need the frame size. What's the most efficient way to solve this?

Comment: @ConveniencePatterns Not sure I understand. You want your tiles to have a constant size of 100x100, but the number of tiles should change according to the size of the frame, which should be maximal? And you don't want to allow resizing? In any case, it should be a separate question.