# JButton show on hover Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, hidden

I'm currently trying to make a basic Java Chess game where a ChessBoard is initialized and populated with ChessSquares. Every time I set the window to visible each JButton does not show up unless hovered over. How do I stop this?

ChessBoard

```
public class ChessBoard extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel p = new JPanel();
    private ChessSquare[][] board = new ChessSquare[8][8];

    public ChessBoard(){

        //Specify frame window.
        setSize(640,640);
        setTitle("Chess");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add panel to frame window.
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        setContentPane(p);

        //Populate Chess Board with squares.
        for(int y=0; y<8; y++){
            for(int x=0; x<8; x++){
                board[x][y] = new ChessSquare(x,y);
                board[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                p.add(board[x][y]);
            }
        }

        //Show window.
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ChessSquare s = (ChessSquare) e.getSource();
        //...
    }
}
```

ChessSquare

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChessSquare extends JButton{

    private int x, y;

    public ChessSquare(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
}
```

[On Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1f0L.png) |
[After Mouse Over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5c18.png)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556). 3) Add `@Override` notation to the `getX()` / `getY()` methods to **not** get a compile error message. This in turn indicates a) they already exist b) it's probably unwise to mess with the existing versions. Ultimately, I've rarely seen a good reason to override component classes, and in this case, it's a (provably - given the result) bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Add `@Override` notation to the `getX()` / `getY()` methods to ***not*** get a compiler error message. This in turn indicates:

- Those methods already exist.
- It's probably unwise to mess with the existing implementations.

Ultimately, I've rarely seen a good reason to override component classes, and in this case, it's a (provably - given the result) bad idea.

This MCVE supports that the problem is in the `ChessSquare` component by replacing them with standard buttons in the `ChessBoard` class. It works just fine, despite that there are some further problems in the code (e.g. no call to `pack()` & guessing the needed size of the GUI, which in this case, leads to a chess board that is **not square**)<sup>1</sup>.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChessBoard extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel p = new JPanel();
    private JButton[][] board = new JButton[8][8];

    public ChessBoard() {

        //Specify frame window.
        setSize(640, 640);
        setTitle("Chess");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add panel to frame window.
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        setContentPane(p);

        //Populate Chess Board with squares.
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                board[x][y] = new JButton(x + "," + y);
                board[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                p.add(board[x][y]);
            }
        }

        //Show window.
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ChessBoard();
            }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton s = (JButton) e.getSource();
        //...
    }
}
```

1. "**not square**" As opposed to the chessboard seen in [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).

[image]

Comment: Ah, I understand about the overrides, my mistake! Didn't even think of that!

Thank you for your help! I'll just replace the buttons!