# Java GUI coloring a specific grid position on gridLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am writing a chess program, and I am in the step of creating the GUI part of the chess.

To do this

I made a BoardGUI class and a TileGUI class.

The BoardGUI initializes a GridLayout -> loops through the entire grid -> initializes a TileGUI object on each grid.

The TileGUI basically gets the information of the gameBoard -> paints the tile based on its position (either dark or light color) -> draws the Piece as and add it as a JButton object.

This basically initialized my chessboard GUI (Code written below).

My question is, when I try to highlight the movable tiles, I am trying to do :

Get the board information and the x, y position of the selected Piece as parameters -> loop through the entire board -> check if the current tile position is movable -> setBackground(color)

But When I do this, it only colors the tile of the current position of the Piece, not the tile of the movable position.

```
private class BoardGUI extends JPanel {

        BoardGUI() {

            super(new GridLayout(NUM_OF_ROWS, NUM_OF_COLS)); //Place tile on each 

            for(int row = 0; row < NUM_OF_ROWS; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < NUM_OF_COLS; col++) {
                    TileGUI tilePanel = new TileGUI(this, new Point(row, col));
                    add(tilePanel);
                }
            }

            // Invoked when container's subcomponents are modified (added or removed from the container)
            validate();
        }
    }
```

And TileGUI

```
private class TileGUI extends JPanel {

        private Point tileCoord;

        TileGUI(final BoardGUI boardPanel, final Point position) {

            super(new GridLayout());
            this.tileCoord = position;

            paintTile();

            placePieceGraphic(boardSetting);

            validate();

        }


        private void placePieceGraphic(Piece[][] boardSetting) {

            // Adds an empty JButton when the tile is empty
            if( boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y] == null) {
                JButton pieceButton = new JButton();

                pieceButton.setOpaque(false);
                pieceButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                pieceButton.setBorderPainted(false);
                add(pieceButton);

                pieceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "empty tile");
                    }
                });

            }

            if( boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y] != null) {

                // Retrieves the first letter of the class name

                // Retrieves the team name: UP or DOWN

                try {
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(filename + ".png"));
                    JButton pieceButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(image));

                    add(pieceButton);
                    pieceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            highlightValidMovement(getMovablePositions(boardSetting, tileCoord.x, tileCoord.y));   // This tries to highlight the movable tiles

                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }


        private void paintTile() {

            boolean isBrightTile = (this.tileCoord.x % 2) == (this.tileCoord.y % 2);
            boolean isDarkTile = (this.tileCoord.x % 2) != (this.tileCoord.y % 2);

            if(isBrightTile) setBackground(darkColor);
            if(isDarkTile) setBackground(brightColor);


        }

        public ArrayList<Piece> getMovablePositions(Piece[][] piece, int x, int y) {

            ArrayList<Piece> movableList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int row = 0; row < NUM_OF_ROWS; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < NUM_OF_COLS; col++) {
                    if(piece[x][y].canMove(piece, x, y, row, col)) {

                        movableList.add(piece[row][col]);
                    }
                }
            }

            return movableList;

        }

        public void highlightValidMovement(ArrayList<Piece> movablePos) {

            for(Piece pos : movablePos) {
                TileGUI tilePanel = new TileGUI(boardImage, new Point(pos.getX(), pos.getX()));
                setBackground(highlightColor);
                add(tilePanel);

            }

        }

    }
```

Codes that are not important is hidden.

This results in

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: most likely your calculation of the `movablePos` is wrong, but you don't show us this code.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).