# Adding an array of JButton into a JPanel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I am new to Java and I am trying to figure out how to simply add an array of JButton in a JPanel. I've tried using a for loop but it does not work.

Comment: *"I've tried using a for loop but it does not work."* Sure it does. See [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556). Now, as to why **your** attempt is not working, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
yourJPanel.setLayout(null);
for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    yourJPanel.add(yourArray[i]);
    yourArray.setVisible(true);
    yourArray.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use null layout. JPanel itself has FlowLayout. The buttons will display nicely in a linear fashion with JPanel's default layout.

Comment: oh, ok then take that out.

Comment: @user3437460 do all the items in the array already have JLabels assigned to them? If it doesn't, then you have to assign a newly declared variable within the for loop, and then add that to the array.