# How do I make A JPanel grid?

Tags: java, swing

i'm trying to create a gui for chess-like game (6x6 board with less pieces).

creating the board is pretty easy with for loops and JPanels but I have no idea how to put the pieces on top of the JPanel. I tried adding one piece by creating a JLabel object with an icon and add it to JPanel but it doesn't look good.

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel
{
    public static final int LENGTH = 6;
    private final Color[] COLOR_ARRAY = {Color.decode("#FFFACD"), Color.decode("#593E1A")};

    public BoardPanel() 
    {
        //grid layout 6x6
        setLayout(new GridLayout(LENGTH, LENGTH));
        int numView = 0;
        //tiles color determined by odd/even
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
                {
                    add(new TileView(numView, COLOR_ARRAY[j % 2]));
                }

                swap();
            }

    }

    private void swap() {

        Color temp = COLOR_ARRAY[0];
        COLOR_ARRAY[0] = COLOR_ARRAY[1];
        COLOR_ARRAY[1] = temp;
    }
}
```

is there a particular class that i need to use in order to do this properly?
default board:

[image: default board]

board with one piece:

[image: board with one piece]

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142686/making-a-robust-resizable-swing-chess-gui)

Comment: Adding a JLabel with an icon to the JPanel sounds like a good idea. What about it "doesn't it look good"?

Comment: See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the board right, just handle the color change :

```
class BoardPanel extends JPanel
{
    public static final int LENGTH = 6;
    private final Color[] COLOR_ARRAY = {Color.decode("#FFFACD"), Color.decode("#593E1A")};

    public BoardPanel()   {
        //grid layout 6x6
        setLayout(new GridLayout(LENGTH, LENGTH));
        int numView = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            numView = (numView == 0) ? 1:0;
            for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
            {
                add(new TileView(COLOR_ARRAY[numView]));
                numView = (numView == 0) ? 1:0;
            }
        }
    }
}

class TileView extends JLabel {

    TileView(Color color) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

Trying to add another component (the piece) to the board (gridlayout) messes it up. 
What you want to do is add another `JPanel` that contains the pieces. 
The pieces `JPanel` needs to be transparent, so the board under it, is visible. One way to achieve it in swing is to use a glass pane :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Chess extends JFrame {

    public Chess()  {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add( new BoardPanel());          //add underlaying board
        setGlassPane(new PiecesPanel()); //add glass pane
        getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Chess();
    }
}

class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

    public static final int LENGTH = 6;
    private final Color[] COLOR_ARRAY = {Color.decode("#FFFACD"), Color.decode("#593E1A")};

    public BoardPanel()   {
        //grid layout 6x6
        setLayout(new GridLayout(LENGTH, LENGTH));
        int numView = 1;
        //tiles color determined by odd/even
        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            numView = (numView == 0) ? 1:0;
            for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
            {
                add(new TileView(COLOR_ARRAY[numView]));
                numView = (numView == 0) ? 1:0;
            }
        }
    }
}

//container for pieces
class PiecesPanel extends JPanel {

    public static final int LENGTH = 6;
    PiecesPanel(){

        setOpaque(false); //make it transparent
        setLayout(new GridLayout(LENGTH, LENGTH));
        JComponent piece = new Piece();
        add(piece);
    }
}

class TileView extends JLabel {

    public static final int SIZE = 100;
    TileView(Color color) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(color);
    }
}

class Piece extends JLabel{

    Piece() {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://dl1.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2017/08/15/9b37ca73-de21-4998-ae7a-07d2915a551e/thumbnail/64x64/0cd91f1c045919af6bdafab3a6f07f99/imgingest-6339051052035379444.png");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();  }
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(url));
        setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** the Piece image link is dead. Use https://findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/64/pawn.png instead

---

[image]

Comment: amazing sir, i will implement this thank you for your help :).

Comment: I am glad it helps