# Adding image files to Java Applet

Tags: java, user-interface, applet, awt

I have drawn a 8x8 chessboard in JAVA using java.awt and java.applet. Now, I want to add an image file (PNG) of a knight onto the chessboard and move it. How to do this?

I have the following code that draws the chessboard:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class ChessBoard extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<640;i+=160)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<640;j+=160)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(i,j,80,80);
            }
        }
        for(int i=80;i<640;i+=160)
        {
            for(int j=80;j<640;j+=160)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(i,j,80,80);
            }
        }
        g.drawRect(0,0,640,640);

    }
}
```

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0IDg.jpg)

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 3) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) ..

Comment: .. for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 4) See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556). It uses Swing buttons (which support an icon) as the chess board places. Makes things much easier.