# Jpanel Ghost Pieces in Chess Game

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, pastebin

so I am writing a chess gui for a class following a console variant of the game being written. I have been using the swing gui tools for this and I have encountered an issue where after each move I make there tends to be a lot of ghost images popping up. I have a picture below of what I mean:

[image: Ghost Chess Pieces]

```
Here is also a pastebin to the code for this section:
```

https://pastebin.com/Lj0Y4zFr

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) *"Here is also a pastebin.."* No. Code, or in this case an MCVE / SSCCE, should be included in the question. Links go stale, and some can't follow them even if they're not. 3) **See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).** You might base your code on that, or at least hot link to the image tile set of chess pieces as that MCVE does.

Comment: `there tends to be a lot of ghost images` - usually indicates a painting problem that you don't clear the background of the panel before doing your custom painting.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `removeAll()` on `cell[i][j]` in `update`, you don't remove them from the `boardGUI`. They are still children of `boardGUI` and will be painted. which is why you see ghost images.

I would recommend setting up an initial board as you do and then just set a different image for the existing `JLabel` and don't try to re-create `JLabels` constantly.