# How do I refresh the panel with a two dimensional button array?

Tags: java, swing, chess

I'm making a chess game in Java. And because I'm a beginner at Swing, I ran into a problem right away. I made a two dimensional array of buttons for the chessboard tiles. The problem is when my first button is clicked I do not know how to refresh that button or the panel it is in.

Here is the code.

```
public class Table extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public JButton[][]tile = new JButton[8][8];
    JPanel gamePAN = new JPanel();
    int size=8;
    Tile[][] tileList = new Tile[8][8];

    private final Color lightTileColor = Color.decode("#FFFACD");
    private final Color darkTileColor = Color.decode("#593E1A");

    public Table() {

        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("Chess");
        initCompoments();

        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        int xsize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
        int ysize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();

        this.setSize(xsize, ysize);

private void initCompoments() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        gamePAN.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(8, 8, 0, 0));
        getContentPane().add(gamePAN);
        gamePAN.setBounds(550, 100, 800, 800);

        pack();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        //gamePAN = new JPanel();
        //gamePAN.setLayout(new GridLayout(size,size));
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<size;j++) {
                if(i%2==0) {
                    if(j%2==0) {
                        tile[i][j] = new JButton();       
                                tile[i[j].setBackground(lightTileColor)              
                                tile[i[j].addActionListener(this);
                        tile[i][j].setSize(10,10);
                        gamePAN.add(tile[i][j]);
                    }else {
                        tile[i][j] = new JButton();
                        tile[i[j].setBackground(darkTileColor);
                        tile[i[j].addActionListener(this);
                        tile[i][j].setSize(10,10);
                        gamePAN.add(tile[i][j]);
                    }
            }else {
                if(j%2==0) {
                    tile[i][j] = new JButton();
                    tile[i[j].setBackground(darkTileColor);
                    tile[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                    tile[i][j].setSize(10,10);
                    gamePAN.add(tile[i][j]);
                }else {
                    tile[i][j] = new JButton(); 
                                 tile[i[j].setBackground(lightTileColor);
                                    tile[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                    tile[i][j].setSize(10,10);
                    gamePAN.add(tile[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    }

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            for(int r=0;r<size;r++) {
                for(int c=0;c<size;c++) {
                    if(ae.getSource()==tile[r][c]) {
        if(tileList[r[c].getPiece()!=null) {
        tileList[r][c].getPiece().kretanje(tile, tileList);
                }
        }

}
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142686/making-a-robust-resizable-swing-chess-gui) is an example, how to make a chessboard using Swing.

Comment: In addition to the example linked by @SergiyMedvynskyy, you'd need to hold an instance of a model for the game state (say in a `ChessGameModel` object). When either player moves, change the game state to reflect the move and update the view (as seen at the link).

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when my first button is clicked I do not know how to refresh that button or the panel it is in

There is no need for all the looping code in the `ActionListener`.

The `ActionEvent` will contain the reference to the button that was clicked.

So in the `ActionListener` you add to the button your basic code would be:

```
JButton button = (JButton)ae.getSource();
button.setIcon(...); // do whatever you want with the button
```