# Set margin about a JPanel of GridLayout in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

[image]
I'm trying to setup the margin about the `JPanel` that it has inside the `GridLayout` refer to the `JFrame`, but I don't found the solution using other answer. I don't know if it's important problem, but also it show only the first button before I go to each button with mouse.
The image is an example, I want to setup the JPanel to start from the corner of the grid of image, because the image has a border (not from code, but from decoration board), the blue squares are the button inside the GridView, but I'm trying to fit the gridView to the image draw grid, using the set property (using proportion of pixel).

```
public class Gui extends JPanel implements View {
  private final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
  private JButton[][] chessBoardSquares = new JButton[5][5];
  private JPanel chessBoard;
  private ImageIcon ArrayWithoutPlayer[] = new ImageIcon[7]; //{1,2,3,4,10,11,12}
  private ImageIcon ArrayWithPlayer[] = new ImageIcon[3]; //{1,2,3}

private JFrame frame; //This is the whole frame

public Gui() {
    createAndShowGUI();
}

private void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Display the window.
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    //frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    //frame.pack();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new ImagePanel( setImageIconFromUrl("/home/amministratore/Documenti/Java/ing-sw-2020-palini-rigutti-vangi/image/SantoriniBoardR.png",800,800).getImage()));

    chessBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5));
    chessBoard.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));
    //chessBoard.setLayout(new BoxLayout());
    //chessBoard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    chessBoard.setBackground(Color.blue);

    //chessBoard.setAlignmentX((float) (2.2/21)*frame.getWidth());
    //chessBoard.setAlignmentY((float) (2.2/21)*frame.getHeight());
    //chessBoard.setMaximumSize(new Dimension((16/21)*frame.getWidth(),(16/21)*frame.getHeight()));
    //chessBoard.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    //chessBoard.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    Insets buttonMargin = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < chessBoardSquares.length; ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < chessBoardSquares[ii].length; jj++) {
            JButton b = new JButton();
            b.setMargin(buttonMargin);

            b.setBorder(null);
            b.setBorderPainted(false);
            b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            b.setOpaque(false);
            chessBoardSquares[ii][jj] = b;
            b.setText("AA");
            chessBoard.add(chessBoardSquares[ii][jj]);
        }
    }

    //chessBoard.setOpaque( false );
    chessBoard.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0,0));
    frame.dispose();
    frame.add(chessBoard);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //chessBoardSquares[0][0].setIcon( ArrayWithoutPlayer[0]); //This is the method to set Icon inside the button
}
}
```

Comment: 1) I'm not clear where the GUI needs this space to appear. Is it: Between the button texts / icons and the button border? Between each button and the next? Around the panel containing the buttons? Somewhere else? 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556). (Not directly related, but you might get some tips from it.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank for the comment, I just add an example for improve the question

Comment: *"I just add an example for improve the question"* I don't find the edit to be any more clear. (shrug)

Comment: The image is not of any help. Post a SS of your output and then on top of it use paint to draw the border you want

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well the image, maybe now is more clearer, I'm trying to fit the gridView that has inside button to the grid inside the draw image

Comment: You're aware that your background image isn't straight? And that the grid cells aren't equally distributed? I think you'd be better using `GridBagLayout` rather than `GridLayout` for this reason. Unless you're trying to add a border to the whole grid, but still not sure

Comment: @Frakcool thanks for the comment, maybe I try to use GridBagLayout instad of GridLayout and then I edit the answer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to setup the margin about the jpanel that it has inside the GridLayout

```
        //b.setMargin(buttonMargin);
        //b.setBorder(null);
        //b.setBorderPainted(false);
```

I don't think you need all that code.

Instead just set the Border of the button:

```
b.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5) );
```

Edit:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new ImagePanel(...));
…
frame.add(chessBoard);
```

First of all `frame.getContentPane().add(…)` and `frame.add(…)` is the same thing. That is the component will be added to the content pane. The second format is just a shortcut for the first.

So you are attempting to add two components to the BorderLayout.CENTER. This will not work as the BorderLayout will only support a single component in any location.

Swing was designed with a parent/child relationship so it appears you want something like:

> - JFrame (content pane)
>
>   - ImagePanel
>
>     - chessBoard

So your logic should be something like:

```
ImagePanel background = new ImagePanel(…);
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
background.add(chessPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(background, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now you have your parent/child relationship between the components.

```
frame.setSize(800, 800);
```

Don't set the size of the frame. (800, 800) is the wrong size. If your ImagePanel is (800, 800) then the frame must be bigger because the frame also includes the title bar and the border.

So instead your logic should be:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The pack() method will allow the frame to determine its own preferred size AFTER all the components have been added to the frame.

Note:

In you ImagePanel class you will also need to implement the `getPreferresSize()` method of your Image. This will allow the pack() method to work properly. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for a working example.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't specify that the margin is about the GridLayout to frame, now I edit the quesiton

Comment: Then please provide ASCII art or an image that shows what you're trying to do @L.Ros.

Comment: @Frakcool thanks for the comment, I just add an example of image for improve the question

Comment: Still not sure I'm understanding your problem. You can use `setBorder(…)` on any component. See edit for other problems with your code.