# Java swing setLocation / setSize not working for JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I have made a chess game where Inside the JFrame there is a boardPanel (chessboard) and a sidePanel (contains buttons like flipBoardButton).
The whole JFrame has a Dimension of 900x640 and the boardPanel therefore is 640x640.

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public BoardPanel() {
    this.setSize(640, 640);
    this.setLocation(0, 0);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){

    boolean white = true;
    for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            if(white){
                g.setColor(new Color(235, 235, 235));
            }
            else{
                g.setColor(new Color(166, 123, 90));
            }
            g.fillRect(x*80, y*80, 80, 80);
            
            white = !white;
        }
        white = !white;
    }
    
    for(Piece p : BoardHandler.piecesOnBoard)
    {
        Image image;
        image = p.getImage();
        g.drawImage(image, p.getX(), p.getY(), this);
    }   
}
```

}

My SidePanel should be on the right (at x=641 y=0) and have a width of 900-640=260 and a height of 640...

```
public class SidePanel extends JPanel{

public SidePanel()
{
    this.setSize(260,640);
    this.setLocation(641, 0);   
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    
    g.setColor(new Color(50,50,50));
    g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}
```

}

This is how I implemented both the panels (usual stuff):

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chess");
    BoardPanel boardPanel = new BoardPanel();  
    SidePanel sidePanel = new SidePanel();
    frame.add(boardPanel);
    frame.add(sidePanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

And I thought everything is working because this is what I got:

[image: Picture of the Game]

BUT: when I go into SidePanel calss and change the setSize to 100x100 or when I set the Location to 700,0 , I get the SAME result !
However, when I change Location / Size in the BoardPanel class, it works perfectly fine ?! (the chessboard then gets rearranged/resized)
How is this possible when I used the "same" code for both classes !?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they aren't conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) See also [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556).

Comment: Yes I will make a resizable one afterwards (using gridlayout or whatever else there is) but for now I just want to finish this quickly since the game is done already and I only need the sidePanel to function. (the buttons etc. are all already done )

Comment: *"I will make a resizable one afterwards"* A non-resizable GUI should also use layouts. Where is that MRE / SSCCE? *"I just want to finish this quickly"* Good luck with that. I'll go help people with no urgency. After all, this is purely academic to people helping for free. If you want immediate fixes, maybe your should hire someone.

Answer (score 1):

> The whole JFrame has a Dimension of 900x640 and the boardPanel therefore is 640x640.

The frame and boardPanel can't possibly have the same height because the frame has a border and a titlebar. Don't attempt to set the size/location of components. That is the job of layout managers.

Many issues:

1. Swing components are responsible for determining their own size. So when you do custom painting you need to implement the `getPreferredSize()` method so the layout manager can do its job.

For the boardPanel is would be something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(640, 640);
}
```

2. By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout. You do NOT specify a constraint when you add your components to the frame, so be default each component is added to the CENTER. However, only the last component is managed by the BorderLayout so it will  set the size/location of the sidePanel, which is why your attempt to do so is ignored.

Because the BorderLayout ignores the chessBoard your attempt to set the size/location appears to work.

However you should not attempt to set the size/location. Let the layout manager do its job.

Instead your code should be:

```
frame.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(sidePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

3. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method, not paint() and you always invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` first to make sure the background of the panel is cleared.
4. Custom painting is relative to the component, not relative to its location in the frame.

The following code in your sidePanel class is wrong:

```
g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

The getX()/getY() is wrong. If you really need to do custom painting then you should just use (0, 0).

However, there is no need to even use custom painting.

In the constructor of your class you just use:

```
setBackground( new Color(...) );
```

and the background will be painted automatically.