# How to extend JComponent and use it to write a customized game board?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am trying to teach myself more about graphics in Java. To do this I'm trying to build a chess game. I've hit my first roadblock at making the board. My thought here is that I would have a extension of JComponent called "Square" that would be my container for both the color of the board square and the piece on that square (if any). To start with I haven't attempted to include any representation of the piece yet, just the square colors. Later on I hope to have an abstract "Pieces" class that is extended by multiple subclasses representing all the different types of pieces, and add those to each Square as applicable.

When I execute the following, I only get one black square in the upper left hand corner.

ChessBoardTest.java

```
public class ChessBoardTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChessBoard Board = new ChessBoard();
    Board.Display();
}
```

}

ChessBoard.java

```
public class ChessBoard extends JFrame {

public static final int FRAME_WIDTH  = 500;
public static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;

// Declare instance variables
private Square[][] square = new Square[rows][cols];
private final static int rows = 8;
private final static int cols = 8;


public ChessBoard() {
    
}

public void Display() {
    JPanel Board_Layout = new JPanel();
    Board_Layout.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
         for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
         {
             if((i+j) % 2 == 0) {
                 square[i][j] = new Square(1);
                 Board_Layout.add(square[i][j]);
             } else {
                 square[i][j] = new Square(0);
                 Board_Layout.add(square[i][j]);
             }
             
         }
    }
    setTitle("Chess Mod");
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(Board_Layout);
    setVisible(true);
}


public void messageBox(String pMessage) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, pMessage, "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

}

Square.java

```
public class Square extends JComponent {

private int color;

public Square(int c) {
    this.color=c;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    if (this.color == 1) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
    } else {
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
    }
    
    g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

}
```

Comment: Generally, you create a logical model of a chessboard and draw that logical model on a single drawing JPanel.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.

Comment: 1) *"teach myself more about graphics in Java. To do this I'm trying to build a chess game"* Note that a [simple chessboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/418556) can be made entirely with standard components. Unless this is intended to add functionality beyond that (e.g. to animate moves of chess pieces), there are better choices for a 'custom painted game'. 2) If custom painting is necessary, it's often better to use a `JPanel` that a `JComponent`. 3) There is no good case here for extending `JFrame`. Just use a standard 'out of the box' frame. ..

Comment: .. 4) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. Please [edit] the question to add 4 space chars ahead of the closing `}` at the end of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only get one black square in the upper left hand corner.

That's mainly because of the following call:

```
g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

`getX()` returns the horizontal pixel offset/location of the `Component` which is invoked upon, relative to the `Container` that contains that `Component`. `getY()` accordingly returns the vertical pixel offset/location of the `Component` which is invoked upon, relative to the `Container` that contains the `Component`.

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return the size of the `Component`.

So imagine that the `Component` at row with index 2 and column with index 3, will have its coordinates at about `x == 3 * w / 8` and `y == 2 * h / 8` where `w` and `h` is the size (width and height respectively) of the parent `Container` (ie the `Board_Layout` panel). Let's assume that `Board_Layout` has a size of 300x300 when you show the graphical user interface... This means that the `Square` at the location I mentioned will only paint the region which starts at `x == 112` and `y == 75` and expands at one 8th of the width (and height) of `Board_Layout` (because there are 8 rows and 8 columns in the grid). But the size of the `Square` itself is also at one 8th of the width (and height) of `Board_Layout`, ie about 37x37. So the painted region which starts and expands from the location 112,75 will not be shown at all (because it lies completely outside the `Square`'s size).

Only the top left `Square` will have some paint on it because its bounds in the parent happen to intersect the drawn region.

To fix this, the location given at the `Graphics` object should be relative to each `Square` and not its parent `Board_Layout`. For example:

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```