# Trying to make checkerboard

Tags: java, object, graphics

I am trying to make a checkerboard given a template from a CS class I am taking. However, when I run it, nothing comes up on the screen. I am guessing I am missing some code to actually draw the squares onto the screen but I have tried a lot of things and still nothing.

```
   import java.applet.Applet;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.util.Random;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.event.*;


   public class Checkers extends JApplet
   {
   private final int MAX_SIZE = 8; 
   private final int APP_WIDTH = 400;
   private final int APP_HEIGHT = 400;
   private final int MAXSIZE = 8;


   Square[][] sq;

   public void paint(Graphics page)
    {

    setBackground(Color.white);
    fillBoard(page); // draws the method that will draw the checkers
    setSize (APP_WIDTH,APP_HEIGHT);

    }

    public void fillBoard(Graphics page)
    {  
       sq = new Square[8][8];

       int x,y;
       Color rb;

       for (int row = 0; row < MAXSIZE; row++)
         for (int col = 0; col < MAXSIZE; col++)
         {
            x = row * (APP_WIDTH/MAXSIZE);
            y = col * (APP_HEIGHT/MAXSIZE);
            if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
               rb = Color.red;
            else
               rb = Color.blue;
            sq[row][col] = new Square (x, y, rb);  
         }
   }

   class Square 
   {


    private int x, y = 0;  
    private Color c;
    private boolean occupied;
    private Color checkerColor;


    public Square (int x, int y, Color c)
    {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.c = c;
    }

    public void setX (int x)
    {
      x = this.x;
    }

    public int getX ()
    {
      return x;
    }

    public void setY (int y)
    {
      y= this.y;
    }

    public int getY ()
    {
      return y;
    }

    public void setColor (Color c)
    {
      c = this.c;
    }

    public Color getColor ()
    {
      return c;
    }

    public void setOccupy (boolean occupied)
    {
      occupied = this.occupied;
    }

    public boolean getOccupy ()
    {
      return occupied;
    }

    public void setCheckerColor (Color c)
    {
      checkerColor = this.checkerColor;
    }

    public Color getCheckerColor ()
    {
      return checkerColor;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      return ("X coordinate: " + x + "\nY coordinate:" + y + "\nSquare color: " + c);
    }


   public void draw (Graphics page)
    {
         page.setColor(c);
         page.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
```

Comment: does this code compile?

Comment: See [How to Make a ChessBoard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21096455/2587435) or [Making a Robust, resizable Chessboard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21142686/2587435)

Comment: Updated to get rid of extra methods I didn't paste in since it's not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `Square#draw`.

Having said that, I would be wary about calling `fillBoard` every time the `paint` method is called, in fact I'd discourage you from overriding `paint` in the first place.

What I might do is check to see if `sq` is `null` in `fillBoard` and only generate the array then.  Back in the paint method, I would simply use a compound loop and `draw` each square.

Instead of overriding `paint` of `JApplet`, you should start with something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, make sure you call `super.paintComponent`!

There are a number of reasons you should do this, but the main one here is `JApplet` is not double buffered, meaning you will get "flashes" as the drawing is updated.  `JPanel` is double buffered by default, saving you a lot of work and time having to implement your own solution...

Once you've done this, take custom panel and add it to the applet.

I would move all the painting logic to it.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will look into what you mentioned. My professor put in the comments in the code, which I have not included for brevity, is we would normally use an init() method but it would be too hard for our level currently. In case I am restricted from changing these parts of the code, how would I go about calling Square#draw?

Comment: Basically, as I said, I would put in a check in `fillBoard` to see if `sq` is `null`, if it is, you would create the border.  Back in your `paint` method, you would use a similar compound `for-loop` as you used in `fillBoard`, but instead of creating `Square`s you would simply call `sq[row][col].draw(page);` - also, the first thing you should do in the `paint` method is call `super.paint(page)`

Comment: Sorry, you should be call `super.paint(page)` in the applets `paint` method not the `Square`'s `draw` method ;)

Comment: Just realized that. Thanks so much and will definitely look into what you said earlier about making it better for my own knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I could see unless I missed something you never actually called a repaint or paint or draw method.  This code is set up differently than most other codes that I have seen trying to accomplish similar tasks and I don't really feel like figuring it all out but you have to actually call the method to draw the image.  However, make sure that you pay close attention to where you call this method because it is rather important to place it correctly otherwise it may not serve its function correctly.