# Cant get ImageIcon to display - swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, imageicon

```
public class GUI
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel squares[][];


    /* Constructor credited to stackoverflow user ranzy
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535417/chess-board-in-java */
    public GUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Chess");
        squares = new JPanel[8][8];
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                squares[i][j] = new JPanel();

                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                } else {
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.orange);
                }
                frame.add(squares[i][j]);
            }
        }

        ImageIcon pawnW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/pawnW.png"));
        ImageIcon knightW = new ImageIcon("images/knightW.png");
        ImageIcon bishopW = new ImageIcon("/images/bishopW.png");
        ImageIcon rookW = new ImageIcon("/images/rookW.png");
        ImageIcon queenW = new ImageIcon("/images/queenW.png");
        ImageIcon kingW = new ImageIcon("/images/kingW.png");

        ImageIcon pawnB = new ImageIcon("/images/pawnB.png");
        ImageIcon knightB = new ImageIcon("/images/knightB.png");
        ImageIcon bishopB = new ImageIcon("/images/bishopB.png");
        ImageIcon rookB = new ImageIcon("/images/rookB.png");
        ImageIcon queenB = new ImageIcon("/images/queenB.png");
        ImageIcon kingB = new ImageIcon("/images/kingB.png");

        squares[0][0].add(new JLabel(rookW));
        squares[1][0].add(new JLabel(knightW));
        squares[2][0].add(new JLabel(bishopW));
        squares[3][0].add(new JLabel(queenW));
        squares[4][0].add(new JLabel(kingW));
        squares[5][0].add(new JLabel(bishopW));
        squares[6][0].add(new JLabel(knightW));
        squares[7][0].add(new JLabel(rookW));

        squares[0][7].add(new JLabel(rookB));
        squares[1][7].add(new JLabel(knightB));
        squares[2][7].add(new JLabel(bishopB));
        squares[3][7].add(new JLabel(queenB));
        squares[4][7].add(new JLabel(kingB));
        squares[5][7].add(new JLabel(bishopB));
        squares[6][7].add(new JLabel(knightB));
        squares[7][7].add(new JLabel(rookB));

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            squares[i][1].add(new JLabel (pawnW));
            squares[i][6].add(new JLabel (pawnB));
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not able to get the icons to display. I've looked through multiple tutorials on this as well as looked at others' code.

[image]

I tried three different ways:

```
ImageIcon pawnW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/pawnW.png"));
ImageIcon knightW = new ImageIcon("images/knightW.png");
ImageIcon bishopW = new ImageIcon("/images/bishopW.png");
```

Comment: How are you compiling and building your code? With intellij?

Comment: Have you tried with the full path? e.g. c:/users/collin/ ...

Comment: @ahmedalkaff The `Class#getResource(..)` method expects a path relative to the classpath.

Comment: The first should work, unless the `images` was never built into the bin. Check the `bin` or its equivalent in Intellij (I have no clue what that is) and see if the `images` is there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I meant as a test he could try it out and if it worked then conclusions can be made about the cause.

Comment: @ahmedalkaff There is no _point_ testing it. Read the javadoc. It will not work.

Comment: Do you have any exception? `getClass().getResource("/images/pawnW.png")` must work for getting resource from classpath.

Comment: It's likely that intellij does not include the `src` directory within it's class path for running application.  Have you compiled and built the project?  Do you have a Jar file?  If you do, unzip and see what's included...

Comment: So.. it looks like the `/chess/src` folder contains only the .java files. If I navigate to the `out` folder, it contains the class files. I stuck the images folder in both the folder containing the class files as well as it's parent directory. No success.
I don't have a jar file/not sure where it would be.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Then I must be doing something magic because it works for me.

Comment: @ahmedalkaff You're probably using something other than `Class#getResource(..)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Here is an example: ImageIcon knightW = new ImageIcon("c:/images/knightW.png"); this is probably not the best way but I meant as a test.

Comment: @ahmedalkaff I feel like I'm repeating myself. `The Class#getResource(..) method expects a path relative to the classpath.` You aren't using that method, so your test is irrelevant to that comment.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please check the question, In the last paragraph stated other ways were tried. What I suggested was an additional one.

Comment: @ahmedalkaff My point is that you should exactly clarify what you are talking about. I made a clarification to your comment. You should do the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Before *anything*, as a side note, `setVisible` should be the *last* thing you do *after* adding all components**

Also check the below

Works fine for me using `getClass().getResource()`

```
 String path = "/images/stackoverflow2.png";

 ImageIcon pawnW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
```

Check all below, then when correct it, **build it**, then run it.

[image]

File Structure *after* **Build**. Images should get copied to class path

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel squares[][];

    public GUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Chess");
        squares = new JPanel[8][8];
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                squares[i][j] = new JPanel();

                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                } else {
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.orange);
                }
                frame.add(squares[i][j]);
            }
        }

        String path = "/images/stackoverflow2.png";

        ImageIcon pawnW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon knightW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon bishopW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon rookW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon queenW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon kingW = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));

        ImageIcon pawnB = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon knightB = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon bishopB = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon rookB = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon queenB = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));
        ImageIcon kingB = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));

        squares[0][0].add(new JLabel(rookW));
        squares[1][0].add(new JLabel(knightW));
        squares[2][0].add(new JLabel(bishopW));
        squares[3][0].add(new JLabel(queenW));
        squares[4][0].add(new JLabel(kingW));
        squares[5][0].add(new JLabel(bishopW));
        squares[6][0].add(new JLabel(knightW));
        squares[7][0].add(new JLabel(rookW));

        squares[0][7].add(new JLabel(rookB));
        squares[1][7].add(new JLabel(knightB));
        squares[2][7].add(new JLabel(bishopB));
        squares[3][7].add(new JLabel(queenB));
        squares[4][7].add(new JLabel(kingB));
        squares[5][7].add(new JLabel(bishopB));
        squares[6][7].add(new JLabel(knightB));
        squares[7][7].add(new JLabel(rookB));

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            squares[i][4].add(new JLabel (pawnW));
            squares[i][6].add(new JLabel (pawnB));
        }

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new GUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alex2410 I figure I at least show my effort so it wasn't wasted. Maybe the OP missed something. Wasn't expecting any praise (up-votes) for it :D

Comment: it was the `set visible` thing... Could you edit your answer to reflect that?